# What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?

Tags: language-agnostic

Personally I like this one:

[image]

P.S. Do not hotlink the cartoon without the site's permission please.

Answer (score 1805, accepted):

Another one from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)
[image: Exploits of a Mom]

Answer (score 1365):

[image]​​​​

Answer (score 933):

I like this one: http://xkcd.com/149/

[image]

(Proper User Policy apparently means Simon Says.)

Answer (score 802):

[image]

Answer (score 744):

[image: The only valid measurement of code quality: WTFs/minute]

Answer (score 676):

I wrote a production website that has the path /dev/random/ return 4 because of this comic.

[image: int get_rand_number(){ return 4;}]

Answer (score 596):

[XKCD Comic 303 - "Compiling"](http://xkcd.com/303/)

[image]

('Are you stealing those LCDs?' 'Yeah, but I'm doing it while my code compiles')

I have this one pinned to the wall facing the entrance to our office :)

Answer (score 543):

[image]

Comment: Randall Munroe, the creator of xkcd, discusses how he actually tested this theory during a talk at Google: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJOS0sV2a24 -- start at 8:26 or so.  The talk is also exciting because Donald Knuth asks the first question!

Answer (score 522):

[image]

Answer (score 484):

Oh! There can be only one:

[image]

It's sooo funny, because it's true :)

Answer (score 474):

[image]

Answer (score 387):

Religious debates are always fun!

[image]

Answer (score 329):

[image]

Answer (score 296):

Of course, [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/353/)!

[image: 353]

Answer (score 279):

[image]​​​​​

Answer (score 261):

[image]

Answer (score 246):

I knew it was true. [XKCD #224](http://xkcd.com/224/)

[image]

"We lost the documentation on quantum mechanics. You'll have to decode the regexes yourself."

Answer (score 244):

Baseline Expectations

[image]

Taken from [Dilbert.com, Sept 12 2008](https://dilbert.com/strip/2008-09-12)

Answer (score 219):

I can't believe someone hasn't put this one:

[image]

Answer (score 213):

[image: Pointers]

Answer (score 208):

[image: Estimation]

XKCD hits the button every time.

Answer (score 201):

[image]

(I hear this is an option in the latest Ubuntu release.)

Answer (score 192):

I didn't know...

[image: Listen to Yourself]

Comment: Apparently, you haven't visited Youtube recently:
http://blag.xkcd.com/2008/10/08/youtube-audio-preview/

Answer (score 171):

On victory:​​​

[image]

Answer (score 156):

xkcd:

[image: Windows 7]

Answer (score 154):

[image]

Answer (score 138):

["When I started programming, we didn't have any of these sissy 'icons' and 'Windows.' All we had were zeros and ones -- and sometimes we didn't even have ones. I wrote an entire database program using only zeros." "You had zeros? We had to use the letter 'O'." -Dilbert (Scott Adams) http://www.mscha.net/tmp/dt19920908.gif](http://www.mscha.net/tmp/dt19920908.gif)

Answer (score 136):

Dilbert is the top favorite, but I've also really enjoyed the xkcd comics the last couple years.  I've got a couple of those posted up in my cube... I try really hard to live by this one.

[image: Compiler Complaint]

Answer (score 129):

[image: Terms and Conditions cartoon from brainstuck.com]

https://brainstuck.com/2008/08/08/t-c/

I'm guessing that this would probably never happen, as agreeing to the terms and conditions is more important than actually reading them (from the software publisher perspective).

Answer (score 122):

[image]

Comment: Here's a good explanation of how to do this sort of problem: http://sites.google.com/site/resistorgrid/grid

Answer (score 111):

One of my favourite :)

[image: If androids someday DO dream of electric sheep, don't forget to declare sheepCount as a long int.]

Answer (score 107):

[Doctor Fun... http://www.ibiblio.org/Dave/Dr-Fun/df200002/df20000210.jpg](http://www.ibiblio.org/Dave/Dr-Fun/df200002/df20000210.jpg)

Answer (score 106):

[image: Can't and shouldn't]

If all bugs were so easy to close.

Answer (score 102):

One more which I liked: No offences.. :)

[how it works](http://xkcd.com/385/)

[image]

Comment: I shared this one with the guys at my old job, explaining that this is how it feels sometimes.  I got some blank looks, and one confused "So all girls are awesome at programming?"

Answer (score 102):

[image]

http://xkcd.com/518/

Answer (score 98):

Without a doubt...

[image: State machines]

Comment: @Anheledir: you can't parse arbitrary nested parentheses with classic regexps.

Comment: Particularly when numbers of opening and closing parentheses don't match :-)

Comment: If I hadn't done some compiler engineering and also some Scheme as part of my degree I'd never get this... however, I personally think it's obscurity is part of what makes it so funny!

Comment: Well, if you restrict the depth of the expressions to something reasonably large, the automaton can handle it. I remember Martin Kay telling us in one class that he spent half a year of his life on converting CFGs into limited-depth FSAs.

Comment: But you can never handle arbitrary expressions of that type with a FSA as you essentially have to construct a different FSA for each and every possible case of the problem.

On a seperate note, does anyone know WHERE this comes from? Found on a random-image thread, but I never knoew the source.

Comment: xan: You can always construct a bigger FSA, but the point is whether or not ONE given FSA can handle ALL expressions of this kind, no matter how long.

Comment: Where does this come from? I only find links to blogspam and image hosting sites for it on Google.

Answer (score 96):

[image: As a project wears on, standards for success slip lower and lower]

("40% of OpenBSD installs lead to shark attacks.  It's their only standing security issue.")

Answer (score 85):

Fax me some electricity, please?

[image: Dilbert Fax]

Answer (score 85):

[image: I'm An Idiot]

Comment: osascript -e "set volume 10"

Answer (score 82):

[image]

[alt text http://www.netfxharmonics.com/Images/WindowsLiveWriter/ComicStrip2.NETandPHPSourceCode_14857/DotNetPhpCartoon02.png](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/Images/WindowsLiveWriter/ComicStrip2.NETandPHPSourceCode_14857/DotNetPhpCartoon02.png)

Comment: BTW, I us PHP too! =P and didn't mean this as a putdown in anyway.  Just found it amusing as a fanboy style comic.  It could apply to any languages in either role.

Comment: Seeing as (afair) Stack Overflow was actually built with .NET, I have decided to retroactively start respecting people who use it

Comment: Wow even comics about .NET suck.

Comment: I rolled my own DAL and 'architectural solution for repurposing business logic to a desktop environment'.  But when I get irritated by the irredemable failure of compile-time type checking (or anything else), jackass PHP fanboys tell me it's because there's something wrong with me, not PHP.

Comment: not funny, and anyone suggesting running sites on IIS for performance reasons, on servers that have an entire GUI OS installed on them, well, no comment

Comment: apphacker: if i dont remember right windows server2008 can be installed in a mode where it only has a console?

Comment: @Petoj Windows 2008 does have such an option.  Another thing to consider is that stackoverflow.com is running on pure MS technologies, Windows/IIS7/MSSQL/.NET and for the number of requests it receives I would say it performs decent.

Comment: Yeah, this comic is pretty moronic.  Take away the specific technology (in this case, .NET) and it's like a third-rate slashdot comment from 1999.  "Hur hur our technology is better." But the worst part is the fact that the technological jargon they spout isn't even impressive.  Moving code between web apps and desktops? Separating database code and logic (which is what a DAL is)? who cares? And it's not like VB is a paragon of type saftey.

Comment: If anything, this is a point *for* PHP: Absence of marketing B.S.

Comment: I'm a .NET dev and am embarassed by this.

Answer (score 71):

Quite demonstrative of why metric based incentives and engineers don't go hand in hand.

[image]

Answer (score 70):

[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd120804s.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd120804s.gif)

Answer (score 63):

[image]

Comment: If someone's personal webpage uses ASP.NET, I give them -20.

Comment: It's nice to see that most ignorance is outside of the Microsoft camp.

Comment: @Deniz: Nothing to be proud of

Comment: Why the hate for ASP.NET? Let me guess... PHP?

Comment: Rails, PHP or ASP.net. Surely Django!

Answer (score 62):

[image]

- (http://thedailywtf.com)

Comment: Their main problem is that the screenshot is a JPEG

Comment: Even better--they created a transparent GIF, then turned it into a JPEG, then saved it again as a PNG--you get the best all 3 formats!

Answer (score 60):

[image: Pwned]

While not specifically about programming per se....wanting to program games is what got me interested in IT in the first place....

anyway this one made me laugh so hard when I saw it!

Comment: i'd have better luck at this version.  i recently tried http://www.quakelive.com/

Comment: on quakelive:  incompatible browser (chrome)

Comment: Alt text: I'm sure a discussion of the reason for the disappearance of adventure games in favor of RPGs would be fascinating

Comment: Mezoid, that's what got us all into IT. If someone told every kid they're gonna pass the rest of their lives coding boring business software, there wouldn't be a single programmer on earth.

Answer (score 60):

John Martz has a [blog entry](http://www.robotjohnny.com/blog/ie6-denial-message-for-momentilecom/) to go with this. [image: IE6 denial message]

Comment: Presumably the comic was made when only those browser existed. Google Chrome and IE 8 were created sometime after 2008 and the other browsers existed before 2008. IE 7 existed in 2005...

Comment: IE7 is just as bad as IE6, if not worse.

Comment: How is IE7 _worse_ than IE6?

Answer (score 55):

Here's a new one from [Dinosaur Comics](http://www.qwantz.com/):

[ladies and gentlemen: mr. stack overflow! http://www.qwantz.com/comics/comic2-82.png](http://www.qwantz.com/comics/comic2-82.png)

Answer (score 53):

[image]

Answer (score 53):

This has made my year.

[image: Some engineer out there has solved P=NP and it's locked up in an electric eggbeater calibration routine. For every 0x5f375a86 we learn about, there are thousands we never see.]

> Some engineer out there has solved P=NP and it's locked up in an electric eggbeater calibration routine.  For every 0x5f375a86 we learn about, there are thousands we never see.

Answer (score 52):

[alt text http://globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/dilbert-xp02.gif](http://globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/dilbert-xp02.gif)

Answer (score 51):

Bit old but still one of my favs:

http://www.ok-cancel.com/strips/okcancel20031003.gif

Comment: Particularly relevant as I saw a Microsoft Surface table today

Comment: @Frank: Not to mention movies, like James Bond: Quantum of Solace.

Comment: "Welcome to LCARS menu system"
Um, except LCARS actually came out OK on Nokia's internet tablets

Comment: Touchscreens are perfectly useful. The millions of them in use in portable gaming consoles, phones, tablet PCs, digitizing tablets, and hundreds of other applications attest to this. This comic only illustrates why touchscreens are impractical as an input device for desktop systems.

Comment: This cartoon is not about touchescreens. It's about touche_less_screens. Check out TED talk - http://www.ted.com/talks/john_underkoffler_drive_3d_data_with_a_gesture.html

Answer (score 51):

http://www.ok-cancel.com/strips/okcancel20031010.gif

Answer (score 50):

Another great Foxtrot comic.  Possibly the most incomprehensible-to-non-geeks comic to sneak into the newspaper funnies.

[image]

Comment: I like the for loop: for (int i=1;i<=numBrainCells;i++) { turnOn(brain[i]) system.out.println("Yawn"); }

Comment: What is it with Foxtrot and starting iteration at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: I'd like to know why the functions getCurrTime and isitaWorkday both either return void or their return value is never used....

Comment: personally, I'd use `brain[i].enable();` or `brain[i].activate();` over `turnOn(brain[i]);`

Comment: @Sorin Comanescu actually brain has to have been initialized and is pointing to null. First brain must be initialized. Also, numBrainCells has to be *declared*!

Answer (score 48):

I love this one:
[image: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/road_rage.png]

Answer (score 48):

[alt text http://www.unt.edu/benchmarks/archives/2004/february04/screwupcolor.gif](http://www.unt.edu/benchmarks/archives/2004/february04/screwupcolor.gif)

This is my everyday.

Answer (score 47):

(it's how people feel          )

[image]

Comment: Being a C# developer, I fail to see the joke. Not because I want to defend C#, but because I don't get it?  What has Ruby and Lisp coders against C#?

Comment: @Statement it's simply this: Ruby is currently the "coolest" language at the moment. Lisp, as you know, is the revered language. The cartoon implicitly implies both Ruby and Lisp are cool. C# on the other hand is a "mainstream language", so, it's not "cool." I also think the cartoon is implying both Lisp and Ruby programmers are fanatics?

Answer (score 45):

[Old black and white version (there's nothing new under the sun) http://www.lore.ua.ac.be/Teaching/SE3BAC/SoftwareSpecCartoon.gif](http://www.lore.ua.ac.be/Teaching/SE3BAC/SoftwareSpecCartoon.gif)

Comment: It's pretty similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/84624#84624 I'm not sure which one came first

Comment: @Doppelganger: This one: Mar 4 '09 at 22:40; the other one: Sep 17 '08 at 15:39. You do the math.

Comment: @Andreas, these pictures are decades old. http://www.businessballs.com/treeswing.htm

Comment: This is good too: http://www.businessballs.com/businessballs_treeswing_pictures.htm

Answer (score 43):

[The very first bug bash](http://www.bugbash.net/comic/1.html) is great!

http://www.bugbash.net/strips/bug-bash20050521.gif

Answer (score 43):

[alt text http://i44.tinypic.com/f07yh3.jpg](http://i44.tinypic.com/f07yh3.jpg)

Answer (score 42):

[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd101305s.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd101305s.gif)

[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd101505s.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd101505s.gif)

[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd101705s.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd101705s.gif)

Answer (score 41):

The 1337 set of comics from xkcd, starting with:
[image: The main thing I love is the thought of Stallman engaging RIAA agents in sword fights towards the end :)]

Answer (score 41):

[image: https://www.cartoonstock.com/lowres/bro0048l.jpg]

Answer (score 40):

[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd011406s.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd011406s.gif)

Answer (score 40):

[Real Programmers Code in Binary http://zeljkofilipin.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/real-programmers-code-in-binary.jpg](http://zeljkofilipin.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/real-programmers-code-in-binary.jpg)

According to http://homepages.strath.ac.uk/~cjbs17/computing/binary.html author of this image is Chris Kania and original is at http://www.kaniamania.com/html/1190.html but the entire site is down at the moment.

Comment: This is nothing to make jokes about. This is actually how I wrote AlgoSim: www.algosim.se

Comment: The Enter is unnecessary. `\r` is 00001101.

Answer (score 40):

[image: Signs your coders don't have enough work to do]

Answer (score 37):

[image: I've got a war to fight!].

Answer (score 35):

Check this From Apple Desicion on APP.[image]

Comment: do they use CSS to hide all the bottom on their site? clever!

Comment: @alex, no they simply publish a 1151real.jpg without all the bottom; your way is good too though. http://www.geekculture.com/joyoftech/joyimages/1151real.jpg

Comment: It took me a while (and had to read the edits) to wonder what I was talking about above!

Answer (score 34):

[image: Hulk MMO Cartoon]

Answer (score 34):

Can't help but love it...

[image]

Comment: According to google (Pi) - (9^2 + (19^2)/22)^(1/4) = 1.00714725 × 10^(-9 )

Answer (score 33):

[alt text http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/08jun/uf011627.gif](http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/08jun/uf011627.gif)

Answer (score 33):

Made for grad students, but applies equally to programmers

[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd012609s.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd012609s.gif)

[PHD Comics - Brain on a Stick](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1126)

Answer (score 33):

[image]

Answer (score 32):

[image: Programmer life]

Answer (score 31):

"Emacs Thumb" from [User Friendly](http://www.userfriendly.org/)

[Emacs Thumb http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/07sep/uf010710.gif](http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/07sep/uf010710.gif)

Answer (score 30):

[alt text http://wondermark.com/comics/190.gif](http://wondermark.com/comics/190.gif)

Answer (score 28):

[image: The doomed project]

a nice [collection](http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~migod/fun/)

Answer (score 28):

I'm surprised this one was missing:

[image: A Bunch of Rocks]

Answer (score 26):

My all time favorite is probably xkcd's "Sudo make me a sandwich" comic, but there are SO MANY good webcomics out there that I thought I'd throw some others out for fun:

A co-worker pointed me to [Sticks and Stones](http://www.arcanology.net/sticksandstones/), which just got started pretty recently. It's sort of an xkcd ripoff, but there's some good stuff in there.
[alt text http://www.arcanology.net/sticksandstones/comics/comic-10.gif](http://www.arcanology.net/sticksandstones/comics/comic-10.gif)

[Hackles](http://hackles.org/) is frequently about programming. This one's probably my favorite:
[Hackles, by Drake Emko & Jen Brodzik http://hackles.org/strips/cartoon334.png](http://hackles.org/strips/cartoon334.png)
It's not quite a programming comic, but I also really dug this strip from [Full Frontal Nerdery](http://nodwick.humor.gamespy.com/ffn/):

[Full Frontal Nerdity by Aaron Williams http://nodwick.humor.gamespy.com/ffn/strips/2008-03-12.jpg](http://nodwick.humor.gamespy.com/ffn/strips/2008-03-12.jpg)

Answer (score 26):

[C++ forest](https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/3502/jim1537.52/0_2805a_2b9e39ea_orig)

[image]

Answer (score 25):

http://www.qwantz.com/comics/comic2-172.png

(sequel to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/448085#448085))

Answer (score 24):

http://ihooky.com/comics/ihooky06.png

Answer (score 24):

[image]

makes me lol

[link](http://xkcd.com/413/)

Answer (score 24):

I can't believe 6 pages of answers and no one mentions [the banana jr 6000](http://toastytech.com/guis/bananaad.gif). How quickly we forget.

http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/3108/bananaadgz4.gif

The other one I love and couldn't find the image for has the punchline "Failure Mr. Jones, is hardly original.  Now sit down."

Also from the Bloom County strip.

Answer (score 24):

I didn't see this one which is one of my favorite xkcd :

[image: Donald Knuth]

(His books were kinda intimidating; rappelling down through his skylight seemed like the best option.)

Answer (score 23):

[alt text http://wondermark.com/comics/352.gif](http://wondermark.com/comics/352.gif)

Answer (score 23):

Hello my favorit is this one

[alt text http://curtis.lassam.net/comics/programmers.png](http://curtis.lassam.net/comics/programmers.png)

Answer (score 21):

[alt text http://www.webcomicsnation.com/memberimages/20070107.png](http://www.webcomicsnation.com/memberimages/20070107.png)

Answer (score 21):

[alt text http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2009-07-31-points-of-view.png](http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2009-07-31-points-of-view.png)

Answer (score 20):

[alt text http://contikistrip.kjempekjekt.com/images/contikistrip3.png](http://contikistrip.kjempekjekt.com/images/contikistrip3.png)

Comment: Whoa, this looks exactly like Order Of The Stick.  http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0001.html

Answer (score 20):

What?! No PhDComics? [Check this out](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=13):
[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd1112.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd1112.gif)

Remember this was 1997!!

Also read the following strips... Hilarious!

Answer (score 20):

I'm going to show my age with the this 1993 classic: [On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog)

[image]

Answer (score 19):

[http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/75.html http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/comics/irreg0075.jpg](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/comics/irreg0075.jpg)

Edited for grammar :P

Answer (score 19):

not directly something about programming, but i guess every programmer knows flowcharts xD

[image]

Answer (score 18):

[alt text http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/1350/pizzasv6.png](http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/1350/pizzasv6.png)

Answer (score 17):

http://cache.g4tv.com/images/ttv/graphics/thescreensavers/3546989.jpg
[alt text http://cache.g4tv.com/images/ttv/graphics/thescreensavers/3546989.jpg](http://cache.g4tv.com/images/ttv/graphics/thescreensavers/3546989.jpg)

Answer (score 17):

[alt text http://i40.tinypic.com/12649i1.png](http://i40.tinypic.com/12649i1.png)

Answer (score 17):

Lately I started reading Geek Hero Comic. My favorite parts so far:

[alt text http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2008-10-17-How-to-improve-productivity.png](http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2008-10-17-How-to-improve-productivity.png)
[alt text http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2008-10-21-The-art-of-programming.png](http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2008-10-21-The-art-of-programming.png)

Answer (score 16):

[alt text http://wondermark.com/comics/128.gif](http://wondermark.com/comics/128.gif)

(guess you have to work on sev zero bugs to get this one)

Answer (score 15):

[Dilbert http://www.laputan.org/images/pictures/elbonia-900406.gif](http://www.laputan.org/images/pictures/elbonia-900406.gif)

This is something I found reading about anti-patterns.

Answer (score 15):

[alt text http://www.bugbash.net/strips/bug-bash20060227.gif](http://www.bugbash.net/strips/bug-bash20060227.gif)

Answer (score 15):

This is old, I'm totally not sure about the permissions and I'm ready to remove it.[alt text http://img120.imageshack.us/img120/8456/easycfm4.jpg](http://img120.imageshack.us/img120/8456/easycfm4.jpg)

Answer (score 13):

I think the IT consultant's image is the best:

[Reasons why people who work with computers have a lot of spare time](http://eviljaymz.com/files/whypeopleseemtohavefreetime.png)

(linking because the picture's pretty big)

Answer (score 12):

Just had to put this here

http://www.implementingscrum.com/images/070806-scrumtoon.jpg

From [here](http://www.implementingscrum.com/section/blog/cartoons/)

Answer (score 12):

Ten reasons you know you're living in 2009

1. You accidentally enter your password on the microwave.
2. You haven't played solitaire with real cards in years.
3. You have a list of 15 phone numbers to reach your family of 3.
4. You e-mail the person who works at the desk next to you.
5. Your reason for not staying in touch with friends and family is that they don't have e-mail addresses.
6. You pull up in your own driveway and use your cell phone to see if anyone is home.
7. Every commercial on television has a web site at the bottom of the screen.
8. Leaving the house without your cell phone, which you didn't have the first 20 or 30 (or 60) years of your life, is now a cause for panic and you turn around to go and get it.
9. You get up in the morning and go online before getting your coffee.
10. You're reading this and nodding and laughing. :)

Comment: Wrong thread; try the programmer jokes one. (And none of these are programming-related anyway.)

Comment: So true.. almost all of it! It's actually sad to realize this!!

Comment: When a hack am I living? I do not laugh :(

Comment: -1. First, not a cartoon. Second, it's not about programming. Third, it's been swirling around the interwebs since before 2004.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Comment: from http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9rvkn/i_made_this_comic_in_my_assembly_language_class/

Comment: add esp , 8;don't forget anything

Answer (score 10):

[You vs Technology  http://www.weblogcartoons.com/cartoons/you-v-tech.gif](http://www.weblogcartoons.com/cartoons/you-v-tech.gif)

Answer (score 10):

For an Agile shop ... THIS is fantastic... As a dev, it just speaks volumes.

Great Fun: [from Implementing Scrum](http://www.implementingscrum.com/2006/09/11/the-classic-story-of-the-pig-and-chicken/) by Clark & vizdos.

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29 in the end, the comic made itself be programmer related :P

Answer (score 10):

**SPOILER ALERT!!!**

[image: Cutting Edge]

Comment: its too much of a stretch to think programmers play computer games

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[It is hideous but I can't look away.  THE KRAMER http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2009-08-19-a-coding-paradox.png](http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2009-08-19-a-coding-paradox.png)

Answer (score 7):

There's a Russian version of [Bash.org](http://bash.org/) at [Bash.org.ru](http://bash.org.ru). What they do now is they take favorite quotes and turn them into cartoons or comic strips. Here's one of my favorite ones:
[Tester http://s.bash.org.ru/img/67c5y2emi7vwmrnd263759.jpg](http://s.bash.org.ru/img/67c5y2emi7vwmrnd263759.jpg)

1. We've got a clever tester now 
   -What do you mean?
2. He's found bunch of stuff... A funny symbol there, a weird key combination here. He's real good
3. But sometimes... I really want to smash his face

Link to site: http://bash.org.ru/comics/20080111

Comment: thats...not really funny. In Russian OR English.

Comment: Neither is Doonesbury. Actually this is funnier than Doonesbury. Actually sticking a freshly sharpened pencil under your eyelid and blinking fiercely is better than Doonesbury.

Comment: In soviet Russia jokes laugh at you.

Answer (score 7):

[From Bug Bash](http://www.bugbash.net/comic/114.html):

[alt text http://www.bugbash.net/strips/bug-bash20070723.gif](http://www.bugbash.net/strips/bug-bash20070723.gif)

Comment: I don't get it.  Is the punchline that she has a moustache?

Answer (score 7):

[alt text http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2009-08-03-hardcoded-limits.png](http://www.geekherocomic.com/comics/2009-08-03-hardcoded-limits.png)

Was [I can do stackoverflow in a weekend](http://blog.bitquabit.com/2009/07/01/one-which-i-call-out-hacker-news/) the inspiration for this cartoon?

Answer (score 6):

Tragically, my favorite cartoon is too old to be on the interwebs.

It's from Datamation.  (Remember Datamation?)  A man is sitting at a desk.  There are bits of electronics everywhere.  Rubble is strewn into every corner of the room.  His face and hair are singed.

He is thinking "It's never done *that* before."

Comment: Had that up in my cubicle for years; wish I could find a copy of it

Answer (score 6):

[alt text http://images.orkut.com/orkut/albums2/ATgAAAB3idBHMFYig7ck6I4oqJ8HtkBHuqkha0UeOIkUaSj8LqiwUPIFIkQVJp2eMtTyQOpxLY3R6XSqqo6vsgv-wURQAJtU9VCzBj_EgcyVWltZNcREVSR-daV-1w.jpg](http://images.orkut.com/orkut/albums2/ATgAAAB3idBHMFYig7ck6I4oqJ8HtkBHuqkha0UeOIkUaSj8LqiwUPIFIkQVJp2eMtTyQOpxLY3R6XSqqo6vsgv-wURQAJtU9VCzBj_EgcyVWltZNcREVSR-daV-1w.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

[http://www.qwantz.com/comics/comic2-1512.png](http://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=1491)

Answer (score 6):

```
HAI
CAN HAS STDIO?
I HAS A VAR
IM IN YR LOOP
    UP VAR!!1
    VISIBLE VAR
    IZ VAR BIGGER THAN 10? KTHXBYE
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
KTHXBAI
```

Taken from :http://lolcode.com/
KTHXBAI!!

Comment: +1 no cartoon but funnier than all of the posted geekherocomics

Answer (score 5):

**The Contiki Strip**

A comic set in a small Norwegian software company. All text in English. Check it out at http://contikistrip.kjempekjekt.com

[Contiki Strip http://contikistrip.kjempekjekt.com/images/contikistrip5.png](http://contikistrip.kjempekjekt.com/images/contikistrip5.png)
[Contiki Strip http://contikistrip.kjempekjekt.com/images/contikistrip7.png](http://contikistrip.kjempekjekt.com/images/contikistrip7.png)

Answer (score 5):

["Helping" out fellow programming co-workers](http://www.businesscasualcomic.com/index.php?date=20090422)

Answer (score 5):

This is my personal favorite... and the name of all my alpha releases!
[alt text http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd071009s.gif](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd071009s.gif)

[original link](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1197)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Static]

Answer (score 4):

http://shortminds.com/comics/2008-09-19.jpg

Check out [Shortminds.com](http://www.shortminds.com) for more

Comment: Except input is a self-closing tag.

Comment: @kaji except self-closing elements like <input />

Answer (score 4):

[image: https://roodiedoodie.files.wordpress.com/2008/01/robots8.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

How about a [math cartoon](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/math-out.html#crunchly73-05-18)?

[alt text http://catb.org/jargon/html/graphics/73-05-18.png](http://catb.org/jargon/html/graphics/73-05-18.png)

Answer (score 3):

http://hackles.org/cgi-bin/archives.pl?request=75
[Hackles http://hackles.org/strips/cartoon75.png](http://hackles.org/strips/cartoon75.png)

Answer (score 3):

**Babbage and Lovelace Vs The Client**

*Includes historical notes*

- [Part 1](http://sydneypadua.com/2dgoggles/babbage-and-lovelace-vs-the-client/)
- [Part 2](http://sydneypadua.com/2dgoggles/lovelace-and-babbage-vs-the-client-pt-2/)

Answer (score 1):

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/879/billgateslastmoments.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/879/billgateslastmoments.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is from [Steve Yegge talking about the verbosity of Java](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/10/egomania-itself.html).

Comment: Steve Yegge talking about verbosity. How ironic.

Answer (score -2):

http://wondermark.com/c/2008-11-25-464forgot.gif

Comment: Is that a humoctopus in the last panel? :-) (Check http://www.everettcc.edu/news/2009/index.cfm?id=9242, or Google it if you've never heard of a humoctopus before.)

Comment: Fun, but I dont quite know how it's programming related.

Comment: I guess folks could see how this is programming related if their management was as inconsistent about what they want them doing as mine is.

You mean nobody else has this problem?

Answer (score -2):

*in which we discuss the philosophy of computer science and programming architecture* by the seemingly-defunct [Standard Out](http://standardout.blogspot.com/):

[in which we discuss the philosophy of computer science and programming architecture http://lh3.ggpht.com/tremendotron/SKFBIbEccOI/AAAAAAAAAI0/qOTa3XJZHho/in%20which%20we%20discuss%20.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/tremendotron/SKFBIbEccOI/AAAAAAAAAI0/qOTa3XJZHho/in%20which%20we%20discuss%20.jpg)

Answer (score -6):

For those who have worked at Accenture www.bigtimeconsulting.com has some awesome ones...

Here are just a few:

[Bold New Changes](http://www.bigtimeconsulting.com/?toon_id=85)

[Advice](http://www.bigtimeconsulting.com/?toon_id=88)

[Dinner](http://www.bigtimeconsulting.com/?toon_id=94)

[Hit and Run](http://www.bigtimeconsulting.com/?toon_id=102)

[Tech Support](http://www.bigtimeconsulting.com/?toon_id=119)

[Quitter](http://www.bigtimeconsulting.com/?toon_id=124)

Answer (score -28):

[image]