# Random number generator in c with max and min

Tags: c, random, numbers, generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, how do I get a specific range of numbers from rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202687/in-c-how-do-i-get-a-specific-range-of-numbers-from-rand)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand();

printf("%d\n", r);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS); }
```

i have this code and i want to make random numbers from 1-6 and fill with them a board [40] any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    int array[40];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<40; i++)
        array[i] = rand()%6 + 1
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);  
}
```

Comment: oh thanks very much and how could i do it 40 times and save all these random numbers?

Comment: something last how can i see how many times appeared the numbers 1-3 and how many times appeared the numbers 4-6?

Comment: and how could i print how many times appeared the numbers 1-3 and how many times appeared the numbers 4-6?