# how to use rand() function with a range in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, how do I get a specific range of numbers from rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202687/in-c-how-do-i-get-a-specific-range-of-numbers-from-rand)
>   [Generate a random number within range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999075/generate-a-random-number-within-range)

I'm stuck on how to use the rand() function and include a range for that random number. I need a random number between 67.00 and 99.99 only to be printed.

This is what I have tried, but failed with...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)

{
    int x = rand();

    if(x>=67.00)
    if(x<=99.99)
          printf("%d\n",x);
        else
        printf("not in range");
}
```

Comment: This has the potential to fail every time you run the program, because `rand` needs to be seeded first if you want the results to be different each time.

Comment: The default seed of rand() is 1.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of *checking* if the result is in the range, you can *force* the result to be in the range that you want:

```
int HIGH = 100;
int LOW = 67;
int rnd = LOW + (rand() % (HIGH-LOW));
```

The value of `rnd` is in the range between `LOW` and `HIGH-1`, inclusive.

If you do not want to force the number into range, change your condition to

```
if(x>=67.00 && x<=99.99)
```

Currently, the `else` belongs to the inner `if`, so the second `printf` does not happen when the number is less than `67`.

Comment: But his requirement is for floats.  Your solution will return only integers.  You should use 6700 and 10000 instead.

Comment: I dont want the number to be forced, so is there an alternative way?

Comment: @RamonCastillo Sure, you can - take a look at the latest edit.

Comment: ok here's the my edited code... also I get the same out being "not in range" which is expected every time I run the program because it is not seeded correct?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)

{
 int x = rand();

 if(x>=67.00 && x<=99.99)
        printf("%d\n",x);
    else
        printf("not in range");