# stdlib.h rand() % range not from 0 to range

Tags: c, random

I'm attempting to pick random indexes from a array in C. [The problem I'm having is that my random numbers aren't going from the range I expect (from 0 to 2047) as this example says that it will](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/). Just from looking at the indexes I get it seems like I'm getting numbers from 1000-1200 instead of the desired range.

Here's the code which calls rand().

```
#define MAXPAGES         2048    // maximum number of processes in the system

//until we have a node, pick random indexes.
while(node == NULL){
    table_index = rand() % MAXPAGES;
    node = table[table_index];
    if(node){
       fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", table_index);
       if(node->current_pages > 0) break;
       else node = NULL;
    }
}
```

I call srand only once in my main function.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    int simulations = 100000;
    // initialize the process hash table
    if(argc > 1){
        removal_algorithm  = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(argc == 3) simulations = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < MAXPAGES; i++) table[i] = NULL;

    printf("Random replacement MMU simulation on %d simulations started\n", simulations);
    Simulate(simulations);
    printf("Random MMU simulation completed. only writing page faults:,");
    printf("%d, read / write page faults: %d, total page faults: %d\n", read_miss, write_miss, read_miss + write_miss);
}
```

Example sequence.

```
 1117
 1069
 1103
 1118
 1071
 1117
 1120
 1092
 1099
 1116
 1121
 1122
 1110
 1116
 1069
 1113
 1120
 1117
 1116
 1071
 1121
 1094
 1110
 1119
 1102
 1117
 1071
 1108
 1102
 1099
 1109
 1109
 1092
 1109
 1120
 1108
 1094
 1101
 1122
 1086
 1110
 1108
 1119
 1120
 1092
 1113
 1117
 1121
```

Comment: This does not appear to be the problem here, but note that `rand() % SOME_VALUE` can be very biased depending on the values of `RAND_MAX` and `SOME_VALUE`. Consider the distribution generated if `RAND_MAX` is *not* a multiple of `SOME_VALUE`.

Comment: How does one get a random range without using the mod operator?

Comment: Worth reading all the answers and comments of [In C, how do I get a specific range of numbers from rand()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202687/in-c-how-do-i-get-a-specific-range-of-numbers-from-rand?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code obviously prints only those indices, for which `table[table_index]` is not null. If `table[0]` is null, it will never print `0`. I.e. this code does not necessarily demonstrate the behavior of `rand()`. Instead it's behavior might be mostly determined by the content of `table`.

Comment: Ahh, crap. That means my tables distribution isn't correct. Well, I'm glad I caught this now at least.