# rand() is outputting the same Number for my while loop but not for my for loop

Tags: c, random, while-loop

I am making this code for a random dice roller and I want to get a random number until I get three 6's on the dice. For some reason this produces the same number for all runs, but on my for loop it works. Can I get some help getting this to work?

The pesky While loop in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int Ran(int max) {
return (rand() % max)+ 1;
}

int main(){

    int max = 6;
    int nsuc = 0, ncount = 0;
    int matt = 40;
    srand((unsigned) time(0));

    for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
        while(!(nsuc >= 3)){
            int nr = Ran(max);
            if(nr < matt){
                ncount++;
                if(nr == 6){
                    nsuc++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Number of rolls until 3 6's = %d\n", ncount);
    }
}
```

Cleaned up the for loop so it's easier to read now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void Shuffle() {
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
}

int Ran(int max) {
return (rand() % max)+ 1;
}

void binomial(int run, int max, int btrials, int *array, int scount){

    for(int j = 1; j<=run; j++){
        for (int i=1;i<=btrials;i++){
            int r = Ran(max);
            if(r == 6){
            scount++;
            }
        printf("Trial %i, roll = %d\n",i , r);
        }
        array[j-1] = scount;
        scount = 0;
        printf("\nEnd of Run %d\n\n",j);
    }

}

int main(){

    int Runs;
    printf("How many runs do you want to do? > ");
    scanf("%d", &Runs);
    printf("\n");

    int bdist[20];
    int distcount = 0;
    int max = 6;
    int btrials = 20;
    int suc[Runs+1];
    int scount = 0;



    Shuffle();
    binomial(Runs, max, btrials, suc, scount);

    printf("All counts of succesful 6 rolls.\n");

    /*
    for(int z = 1; z<=Runs; z++){
        printf("Run %d has %d 6's\n", z, suc[z-1]);
    }
    */

    for(int k = 0; k<=btrials; k++){
        for(int j = 1; j<=Runs; j++){
            if(suc[j-1] == k){
                distcount++;
            }     
        }
        bdist[k] = distcount;
        distcount = 0;
    }

    for(int t = 0; t<=btrials; t++){
        printf("Number of runs with %d 6s = %d\n", t, bdist[t]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `nsuc` or `ncount` in the first version with the while loop. After the first time thru, they still have their values from the previous loop so you get the same output.

Comment: Yea you got it, I was so focused on it being rand() I just forgot to do something so basic. Thanks for the help, I supposed I should take a break from coding for today.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer strictly related to the question, but something I noticed.

If I recall, generating ranged random numbers using the `(rand % max)+ 1` idiom is not advised.

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999075/generate-a-random-number-within-range/2999130#2999130).

[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202687/how-do-i-get-a-specific-range-of-numbers-from-rand)

Comment: This does not answer the question, as you said. It would make a fair comment. Please wait until you have a few more points – be warned, posting comments as answers will *not help* you getting there.

Comment: Will do, just wanted to do my part.