# Bubble Sort on Linked List Shortening List

Tags: c, sorting

```
typedef struct Node{
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
}Node;

Node* initNode(){
  Node* newN = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newN->data = rand() % (1000 -0);
  newN->next = NULL;
}

void addNodes(int amount, Node* first){
  Node* cur = first;
  while(cur->next != NULL){
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i <= amount; i++){
    cur->next = initNode();
    cur = cur->next;
  }
}

void printNodes(Node* first){
  Node* cur = first;
  int loopC = 0;
  while(cur->next != NULL){
    printf("%d-", cur->data);
    loopC++;
    cur = cur->next;
  }
}
```

beginning of areas causing problem
I think that it is something wrong with the sort or swap functions causing the shortening of the linked list, not sure though.

```
void swap(Node* prev, Node* cur, Node* first){
  Node* next = cur->next;
  if(next==NULL){return;}
  Node* nextO = next->next;
  cur->next = nextO;
  if(prev != NULL){prev->next = next;}
  else{first = next;}
  next->next = cur;

}

void bubbleSort(Node* first){
  int switchC = -1;
  while(switchC != 0){
    switchC = 0;
    Node* cur = first;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    Node* next = NULL;
    while(cur->next != NULL){
      next = cur->next;
      if(next->data <= cur->data){
        swap(prev, cur, first);
        switchC++;
      }
      prev = cur;
      cur = next;      
    }
  }
}
```

end of areas causing problem

```
void main(){
  Node* first = initNode();
  addNodes(10, first);
  printNodes(first);
  bubbleSort(first);
  printNodes(first);
}
```

inputed linked list: Node 0: value:383-Node 1: value:886-Node 2: value:777-Node 3: value:915-Node 4: value:793-Node 5: value:335-Node 6: value:386-Node 7: value:492-Node 8: value:649-Node 9: value:421-Node 10: value:362

Outputed Linked List: Node 0: value:383-Node 1: value:386-Node 2: value:421-Node 3: value:492-Node 4: value:649-Node 5: value:777-Node 6: value:793-Node 7: value:886

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  Such as which statement is causing the issue, what are the values of the variable, what are the expected values.

Comment: I highly recommend drawing the linked list as you use the debugger.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: `first = next` in `swap` is pointless, so probably you think it is doing something that it isn't.

Comment: OT: `rand() % (1000 -0);` really isn't a good way to get random numbers in the range of `0-999`.  Unless you divide `RAND_MAX` evenly, there will be some bias introduced into your results.  When your divisor for the `%` operation gets to be a large enough fraction of `RAND_MAX`, that bias can affect your results in ways that matter if you're doing anything important.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202687/how-do-i-get-a-specific-range-of-numbers-from-rand (for starters - there's a lot more out there on this subject)

Comment: Also, please pick one language.  There's no such programming language as "C/C++".

Comment: @WilliamPursell could you elaborate on how it's pointless, it is just changing what first points to when first first becomes pointed to.

Comment: `first = next` makes an assignment to a local variable which is never used before the function returns.  You probably meant to pass `Node **first` and want to make the assignment `*first = next` which would have an impact on the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You claim that the problem is in your Bubblesort implementation, but there is at least *a* problem in `printNodes()`:

> ```
> void printNodes(Node* first){
>   Node* cur = first;
>   int loopC = 0;
>   while(cur->next != NULL){
>     printf("%d-", cur->data);
>     loopC++;
>     cur = cur->next;
>   }
> }
> ```

Observe that the last node in the list will not satisfy the condition `cur->next != NULL`, and therefore its value will not be printed.  It is worth also mentioning at this point that the representations of the input and output linked lists presented in the OP were not produced by the version of `printNodes()` presented there, which begs the question of where they did come from.

It turns out that you are right about there being a bug in your sort, however.  Both your `swap()` and your `bubbleSort()` are flawed.  They accept the head pointer *by value* and return nothing, so when one of these functions tries to assign a different node to be the head node, that change does not propagate to the function's caller.

There are two possible solutions for that in the `bubbleSort()` function:

1. Pass a pointer to the head pointer:

   ```
   void bubbleSort(Node **first) // ...
   ```

   Erstwhile uses of `first` would need to be adjusted to `*first`.
2. Return the new value of `first`, making it the caller's responsibility to update its head-node pointer.

   ```
   Node *bubbleSort(Node *first) {
       // ...
       return first;
   }
   ```

The same applies to your `swap()` function, but there you have an additional option: restructure `bubbleSort` so that the `prev` argument to `swap()` is never null.  You can do this by temporarily inserting a dummy head node in front of the true head, and structuring the sort passes so that the dummy is never evaluated for exchange with its successor.  This permits you to make the head node an ordinary case instead of a special one.  I leave the details to you to work out if you wish, but here's a start:

```
void bubbleSort(Node **first) {
    Node dummy = { .next = *first };

    // ...

    *first = dummy.next;
}
```

If you pursue this then you should find that `swap()` does not need the third argument, as its `prev` will always be non-NULL (sometimes it may be `&dummy`).  The simplification may even be enough that you decide you don't need a separate `swap()` function in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the help on printNodes(), I changed the printNodes function slightly in an attempt to make the input and output more coherent. However, all changing printNodes() does is display one more node, any advice on how to fix the sorting or swap function?

Comment: Yes, @ZacharyAllwein.  See answer updates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a `prev` pointer in your `bubbleSort` function.
Also, you don't have to change pointers in your `swap` function. Since the size of the list won't change, you can merely swap the `data` field.

Be careful no to squeeze your code this much. It's hard to follow.
Start with a known data (such as the vector `100,99,...,89` below).
Will be much easier to debug.

Here's a possible fix with minimum changes to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
}Node;

int count = 100;

Node* initNode(){
  Node* newN = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newN->data = count--;
  newN->next = NULL;
}

void addNodes(int amount, Node* first){
  Node* cur = first;
  while(cur->next != NULL){
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i <= amount; i++){
    cur->next = initNode();
    cur = cur->next;
  }
}

void printNodes(Node* first){
  Node* cur = first;
  int loopC = 0;
  while(cur != NULL){
    printf("%d-", cur->data);
    loopC++;
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void swap(Node* node1, Node* node2)
{
  int tmp = node2->data;

  node2->data = node1->data;
  node1->data = tmp;
}

void bubbleSort(Node* first)
{
  int switchC = -1;

  while(switchC != 0) {

    switchC = 0;
    Node* cur = first;
    Node* next = NULL;

    while ((next = cur->next) != NULL) {

      if(next->data <= cur->data) {

        swap(cur, next);

        switchC++;
      }

      cur = next;
    }
  }
}

void main()
{
  Node* first = initNode();

  addNodes(10, first);

  printNodes(first);

  bubbleSort(first);

  printNodes(first);
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out
100-99-98-97-96-95-94-93-92-91-90-89-
89-90-91-92-93-94-95-96-97-98-99-100-
```