# ranged random numbers in C

Tags: c, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a random number from within a range - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c)

I'm looking for something I can use in C that will give me a random number between a and b. So something like rand(50) would give me a number between 1 and 50.

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c

Comment: @Neil: Those comments will be inserted automatically now, once you vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: @Roger I know - old habits die hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comp.lang.c FAQ: [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [rand](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html) or [random](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/random.html) to get an arbitrary random value, then you can take the result of that and mod it by the size of the range and then add the start offset to put it within the desired range. Ex:

```
(rand()%(b-a))+a
```

Comment: Be aware that unless (b-a) is a power of 2, you will NOT get a uniform distribution here. It will slightly favor the smaller values.

Comment: yes in fact even the man of rand suggests not to use rand()%N to get numbers from 0 to N-1, since the distribution gets skewed a bit. the proposed solution for num from 1 to 10 is `1 + (int) (10.0 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `rand()` and `srand()`.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand