# Some unexplained errors in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int a,n,count;
 count=0; randomize();
 a=1+random(100);  
 cout<<"Enter A No. Between 1 to 100";
 do
  { 
    cin>>n;
    count++;
    if(n>a)
           cout<<"Enter a lower no.";
    else if(n<a)
           cout<<"Enter a higher no.";
    }while(n!=a);
cout<<count;

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The errors are:

- E:\c++\main.cpp In function `int main()':
- 10 E:\c++\main.cpp `randomize' undeclared (first use this function)
- (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
- 11 E:\c++\main.cpp `random' undeclared (first use this function)

Can anyone help me understand why these errors are occurring?

Comment: So far 4 totally duplicate answers :)

Comment: not single helpful for me as in turbo c++ this runs ok but in dev c++

Comment: Side note: the code doesn't need both `<cstdlib>` and `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @user142187 - the answers you've gotten have been very helpful. Those functions are not in standard C nor in standard C++. Using non-standard functions is okay if you don't need portability, but when you try to use multiple compilers you need to write portable code.

Comment: Incidentally, although the code is, formally, C++, the random number stuff is pure C. Nothing inherently wrong with that, but there are much better random number facilities in C++, if you have TR1 or C++11 or Boost.

Comment: @PeteBecker links please

Comment: -1 The question has been answered correctly several times. SO is not an outsourcing company, so read the links and/or google `srand` and `rand` instead of expecting people to write your code for you.

Comment: got the answer thnx to all @PeteBecker can you provide links for the compilers above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`randomize()` is not a standard C++ function, you will have to use `srand(something)` to seed a random number generator, where `something` will ussually be current time (`time(0)`).

Also, `random()` is not a standard function, you will have to use `rand()`

So, something like this (cleaned up a little):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int n, count = 0;
    int a = 1 + (rand() % 100);  
    cout << "Enter A No. Between 1 to 100";
    do
    { 
        cin >> n;
        count++;
        if (n>a)
            cout << "Enter a lower no.";
        else if (n<a)
            cout << "Enter a higher no.";
    } while(n!=a);
    cout << count;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: But keep in mind, that `rand() % N` does not uniformly give a number in the range [0, N). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c

Comment: @MarcusRiemer It is a good approximation in most cases and based on the rest of the code, an absolutely uniform random number is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a function (here: `count=0; randomize();`) named "randomize" - the compiler doesn't know where to find this function, as it's not defined in your code, nor in any header you're including.

I suspect you wanted [`srand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) and [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/).

---

For example - you can rewrite your existing code like the following.  To use this code - you'll need to also `#include <time.h>` in your includes:

```
int main()
{
 int a,n,count;
 count=0; 
 srand(time(NULL)); // use instead of "randomize"
 a = 1 + (rand() % 100); 
 // ... Rest of your code
```

Comment: would be nice if you can finish my work as well, so i can go in weekend.

Comment: @user142187 if you can't use google to figure out how to call a simple function, I suggest you switch majors.

Comment: @user142187 I modified - but the links I posted included all of this as samples, so this at least should give you a starting point...

Answer (score 2):

The methods you're attempting to call are called [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) and [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/).

`randomize` and `random` are not part of the language.

Comment: 343 D:\Dev-Cpp\include\stdlib.h too few arguments to function `void srand(unsigned int)'  342 D:\Dev-Cpp\include\stdlib.h too many arguments to function `int rand()'    after changing this i m getting these errors

Comment: @user142187 I'm not going to write the code for you. Did you click on the links? Did you try to google how to properly use `srand`?

Comment: @user142187 - yes, you need to know what arguments these functions take in order to call them. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

There are no `randomize()` and `random()` functions in standard C. Maybe you mean `srand()` and `rand()`?

Take a look at [this question, on how to correctly "randomise" a number in a given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c). `rand() % N` does not uniformly give a number in the range [0, N).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C++11 compiler that includes `<random>` (if you don't, you can use `boost::random` from Boost library), you can use this class for better pseudo-random numbers:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

class rng
{
private:
    std::mt19937 rng_engine;

    static rng& instance()
    {
        static rng instance_; 
        return instance_;
    }

    rng() {
        rng_engine.seed(
            static_cast<unsigned long>(time(nullptr))
            );
    };

    rng(rng const&);
    void operator=(rng const&);

public:
    static long random(long low, long high)
    {
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<long>
              (low, high)(instance().rng_engine);
    }
};
```

Then you use this to get random numbers in a `[a,b]` interval:

```
long a = rng::random(a, b);
```

You don't need to seed it manually as it will be seeded on first invocation.

Comment: If you're a beginner, you generally don't have to bother with such intricacies, I added this just for the sake of "doing-it-more-in-a-C++-way"