# How can I generate a random number between 0 and 4 in c++?

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a random number from within a range - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c)

I want to generate a random number between 0 and 4 inclusively.  How can I do this in c++?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What have you tried? Googling "generate random number C++" should get you started.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question about C because this question is about C++. In the current version of C++ the correct answer will obviously not involve `rand()`.

Answer (score 6):

You could call `std::rand()`, usning the modulo operator to limit the range to the desired one.

```
std::rand()%5
```

You can also have a look at the new C++11 [random number generation utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: Oh I figured I'd at least have to include another library

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness I show you a C++11 solution using the new `random` facility:

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime> 

int main() {
    std::minstd_rand generator(std::time(0)); 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 4);
    int nextRandomInt = dist(generator);
    return 0;
}
```