# generate random number in a range [l u]

Tags: c, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a random number from within a range - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c)

I saw the following code from [programming pearls](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/sort.cpp)

```
int randint(int l, int u)
{   return l + (RAND_MAX*rand() + rand()) % (u-l+1);
}
```

Can anyone help me explain it?

Can we just use

```
return l + rand() % (u-l+1);
```

Thanks,

Comment: What does `quicksort` have to do with the question?

Comment: @millimoose, it's better to do "swap(l, randint(l, u))" for pre-processing

Comment: @FihopZz So? You're not asking about the quicksort algorithm itself, so it's at best tangentially relevant.

Comment: @millimoose, Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `rand() % n` to get a number between 0 and n-1 is that it has some bias when n is not an exact divisor of RAND_MAX. The higher the value of n, the stronger this bias becomes.

To illustrate why this happens, let's imagine that rand() would be implemented with a six-sided die. So RAND_MAX would be 5. We want to use this die to generate random numbers between 0 and 3, so we do this:

```
x = rand() % 4
```

What's the value of x for each of the six outcomes of rand?

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
```

As you can see, the numbers 0 and 1 will be generated twice as often as the numbers 2 and 3.

When your use case doesn't permit bias, this is a better way to calculate a random number:

```
 (int)((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * (double)n)
```

Comment: by the way: that's also the reason why the most simple random number generators of many modern languages return floating point values between 0.0(inclusive) and 1.0(exclusive) by default: The straight-forward way to turn these into integers between 0 and n is bias-free.

Comment: @Philipp disagree about "The straight-forward way to turn these into integers between 0 and n is bias-free".  By "straight-forward way", I assume you mean `int y = rand_0to1() * n`.  Consider `rand_0to1()` generates `M` different values. Unless `M%n == 0`, there will be bias, albeit small.

Comment: Certainly you wanted `(int)((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)* (double)n)`.  This and the original may be better, but are not biased free for arbitrary `n`.

Answer (score 1):

yes that is ok, check that u>l and you can do only this:

```
return l + (RAND_MAX*rand()) % (u-l+1);
```

***explaination:***

if we would like to generate in union distribution a random integer number in `[0,N]` when `N>0` we would use:

```
 return (RAND_MAX*rand()) % (N+1);
```

since the range is shitted with a constant value `l` in your case we just have to add it to the final result.

*python model:*

```
>>> import random
>>> import sys
>>> for i in xrange(20):
    int(random.random()*sys.maxint%4)


0
1
2
3
1
1
2
2
3
0
3
3
0
2
3
3
1
2
2
3
```