# Parallel Merge-Sort in OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have seen an algorithm for parallel merge-sort in a [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.8006.pdf) paper. This is the code:

```
void mergesort_parallel_omp (int a[], int size, int temp[], int threads) 
{  
    if ( threads == 1)       { mergesort_serial(a, size, temp); }
    else if (threads > 1) 
    {
         #pragma omp parallel sections
         {
             #pragma omp section
             mergesort_parallel_omp(a, size/2, temp, threads/2);
             #pragma omp section
             mergesort_parallel_omp(a + size/2, size - size/2, temp + size/2, threads - threads/2);
         }
         merge(a, size, temp); 
    } // threads > 1
}
```

I run it on a multicore. What happens is that at the leafs of the tree, 2 threads run in parallel. After they finished their work 2 other threads start and so on. Even if we have free cores for all the leaf nodes.

I think the reason is this OpenMP code does not create parallel regions inside parallel regions. Am I correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I think the reason is that OpenMP cannot create parallel regions
> inside parallel regions

You can have a parallel region of parallel region.

> OpenMP parallel regions can **be nested inside each other**. If **nested
> parallelism is disabled**, then the new team created by a thread
> encountering a parallel construct inside a parallel region consists
> **only of the encountering thread**. If **nested parallelism is enabled**,
> then the new team **may consist of more than one thread** ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/stud.10/819-0501/2_nested.html)).

In order to run your code correctly, you need to call `omp_set_nested(1)` and `omp_set_num_threads(2)`.

> Nested parallelism can be enabled or disabled by setting the
> OMP_NESTED environment variable or calling omp_set_nested() function

---

For a better performance instead of sections you can use OpenMP tasks (detailed information and examples about can be found [here](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-task.html)) as follows:

```
void merge(int * X, int n, int * tmp) {
   ...
} 

void mergeSort(int *X, int n, int *tmp)
{  
   if (n < 2) return;
   
   #pragma omp task shared(X) if (n > TASK_SIZE)
   mergeSort(X, n/2, tmp);
   
   #pragma omp task shared(X) if (n > TASK_SIZE)
   mergeSort(X+(n/2), n-(n/2), tmp + n/2);
   
   #pragma omp taskwait
   mergeSortAux(X, n, tmp);
}



int main()
{
   ...
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      #pragma omp single
      mergesort(data, n, tmp);
   }
}
```

The sequential code of the merge algorithm comes from Dr. Johnnie W. Baker [webpage.](http://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Ejbaker/23Workshop/Chesebrough/mergesort/mergesortOMP.cpp). However, the code that I am providing in this answer has some corrections and performance improvements.

**A full running example:**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define TASK_SIZE 100

unsigned int rand_interval(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/
    int r;
    const unsigned int range = 1 + max - min;
    const unsigned int buckets = RAND_MAX / range;
    const unsigned int limit = buckets * range;

    do
    {
        r = rand();
    } 
    while (r >= limit);

    return min + (r / buckets);
}

void fillupRandomly (int *m, int size, unsigned int min, unsigned int max){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    m[i] = rand_interval(min, max);
} 

void mergeSortAux(int *X, int n, int *tmp) {
   int i = 0;
   int j = n/2;
   int ti = 0;

   while (i<n/2 && j<n) {
      if (X[i] < X[j]) {
         tmp[ti] = X[i];
         ti++; i++;
      } else {
         tmp[ti] = X[j];
         ti++; j++;
      }
   }
   while (i<n/2) { /* finish up lower half */
      tmp[ti] = X[i];
      ti++; i++;
   }
   while (j<n) { /* finish up upper half */
      tmp[ti] = X[j];
      ti++; j++;
   }
   memcpy(X, tmp, n*sizeof(int));
} 

void mergeSort(int *X, int n, int *tmp)
{
   if (n < 2) return;

   #pragma omp task shared(X) if (n > TASK_SIZE)
   mergeSort(X, n/2, tmp);

   #pragma omp task shared(X) if (n > TASK_SIZE)
   mergeSort(X+(n/2), n-(n/2), tmp + n/2);

   #pragma omp taskwait
   mergeSortAux(X, n, tmp);
}

void init(int *a, int size){
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       a[i] = 0;
}

void printArray(int *a, int size){
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       printf("%d ", a[i]);
   printf("\n");
}

int isSorted(int *a, int size){
   for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
      if(a[i] > a[i + 1])
        return 0;
   return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        srand(123456);
        int N  = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 10;
        int print = (argc > 2) ? atoi(argv[2]) : 0;
        int numThreads = (argc > 3) ? atoi(argv[3]) : 2;
        int *X = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        int *tmp = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

        omp_set_dynamic(0);              /** Explicitly disable dynamic teams **/
        omp_set_num_threads(numThreads); /** Use N threads for all parallel regions **/

         // Dealing with fail memory allocation
        if(!X || !tmp)
        { 
           if(X) free(X);
           if(tmp) free(tmp);
           return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fillupRandomly (X, N, 0, 5);

        double begin = omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp single
            mergeSort(X, N, tmp);
        }   
        double end = omp_get_wtime();
        printf("Time: %f (s) \n",end-begin);
    
        assert(1 == isSorted(X, N));

        if(print){
           printArray(X, N);
        }

        free(X);
        free(tmp);
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

An had-doc benchmark in a 4 core machine yield the following results:

```
100000000 elements 
1 thread : Time: 11.052081 (s)
2 threads: Time: 5.907508  (s)
4 threads: Time: 4.984839  (s)

A overall Speed up of 2.21x
```

Future improvements will be available on [GitHub](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/OpenMP/MergeSort/main.c).

---

An advance C++ version of parallel version can be found [here](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/old/_media/courses/b4m35pag/lab6_slides_advanced_openmp.pdf). The final algorithm looks like the following:

```
void mergeSortRecursive(vector<double>& v, unsigned long left, unsigned long right) {
   if (left < right) {
      if (right-left >= 32) {
         unsigned long mid = (left+right)/2; 
         #pragma omp taskgroup
         {
            #pragma omp task shared(v) untied if(right-left >= (1<<14))
            mergeSortRecursive(v, left, mid);
            #pragma omp task shared(v) untied if(right-left >= (1<<14))
            mergeSortRecursive(v, mid+1, right);
            #pragma omp taskyield
         }
         inplace_merge(v.begin()+left, v.begin()+mid+1, v.begin()+right+1);
      }else{
         sort(v.begin()+left, v.begin()+right+1);
     }
    }
  }
}


void mergeSort(vector<double>& v) { 
     #pragma omp parallel
     #pragma omp single
     mergeSortRecursive(v, 0, v.size()-1); 
}
```

A reported speedup of `6.61x` for 48 threads.

Answer (score 5):

The modern answer to this question is to use tasks instead of sections. Tasks were added in OpenMP 3.0 (2009) and work better/easier than nested parallelism and sections, because nested parallelism can lead to oversubscription (more active threads than CPUs available), which causes significant performance degradation. With tasks, you have one team of threads matching the number of CPUs and the will work on the tasks. So you do not need the manual handling with the `threads` parameter. A simple solution looks like this:

```
// span parallel region outside once outside
void mergesort_omp(...) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    mergesort_parallel_omp(...)
}


void mergesort_parallel_omp (int a[], int size, int temp[]) 
{  
    #pragma omp task
    mergesort_parallel_omp(a, size/2, temp);

    mergesort_parallel_omp(a + size/2, size - size/2, temp + size/2);

    #pragma omp taskwait
    merge(a, size, temp); 
}
```

However, it can still be problematic to create tasks for too small chunks of work, so it is useful to limit the parallelism based on the work granularity, e.g. as such:

```
void mergesort_parallel_omp (int a[], int size, int temp[]) 
{  
    if (size < size_threshold) {
        mergesort_serial(a, size, temp);
        return;
    }
    #pragma omp task
    mergesort_parallel_omp(a, size/2, temp);

    mergesort_parallel_omp(a + size/2, size - size/2, temp + size/2);

    #pragma omp taskwait
    merge(a, size, temp); 
}
```