# libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable OpenMP parallel Merge Sorting

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, mergesort, libgomp

I am new to OpenMP. I was trying to implement a parallel version of merge sorting. The code of my serial implementation is the same of this, but I did not use the parallelMergeSort function.
My parallel implementation is the following:

```
//PARALLEL MERGE SORT
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>

void merge(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB, int end, int arrOut[]);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[]);
void parallelMergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[], int threads);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int threads, availableThreads;
    int N = 10;
    int my_array[N];
    int outputArray[N];
    int length = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        my_array[i]=rand()%100 + 1;
    }
    //print the array 
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
    }   

    availableThreads=omp_get_max_threads();
    printf("Numero massimo di threads disponibile: %d\n", availableThreads);

    printf("Inserisci numero di threads non superiore a %d: \n", availableThreads);
    scanf("%d", &threads);

    omp_set_nested(1);
    if (omp_get_nested() != 1)
        printf("Errore nested parallelism\n");

    int processori = omp_get_num_procs(); 
    printf("Processori: %d\n", processori);

    if(threads>processori)
        omp_set_num_threads(threads);

    printf("\n--------------\n");

    double start=omp_get_wtime();
    parallelMergeSort(my_array, 0, length-1, outputArray, threads); 
    double end=omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Time: %f", end-start);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} 



void merge(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB, int end, int arrOut[]){
    int i=indexA, j=indexB, k=indexA;
    while(i<=indexB-1 && j<=end){
        if(arr[i]<arr[j]){
            //i=i+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        }
        else{
            //j=j+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<=indexB-1){
        //i++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=end){
        //j++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        k++;
    }
    for(i=indexA; i<=end; i++)
        arr[i]=arrOut[i];
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[]){
    int medium;
    if(inf<sup){
        medium=(inf+sup)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, inf, medium, arrOut);
        mergeSort(arr, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
        merge(arr, inf, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
    }
}

void parallelMergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[], int threads){
    if (threads==1)
        mergeSort(arr, inf, sup, arrOut);
    else if(threads>1){
        #pragma omp parallel sections
        {
            #pragma omp section
            {
            parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, (inf+sup)/2, arrOut, threads);}
            #pragma omp section
            {
            parallelMergeSort(arr, (inf+sup)/2 + 1, sup, arrOut, threads-threads/2);}
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have an error in the parallelMergeSort function, because the `printf("\n--------------\n");` is printed.
The error is the one in title: `libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable`.
I don't know where is the error. I tried to implement following this example: [Parallel Merge-Sort in OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811114/parallel-merge-sort-in-openmp)
I do no think that is a problem of resources because simple programs work. Obviously i made some errors in that function...

Edit: this happens both if i use 2 or 3, or 4 threads, and so on.

EDIT: If I use OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE

```
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT BEGIN
  _OPENMP = '201511'
  OMP_DYNAMIC = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NESTED = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NUM_THREADS = '8'
  OMP_SCHEDULE = 'DYNAMIC'
  OMP_PROC_BIND = 'FALSE'
  OMP_PLACES = ''
  OMP_STACKSIZE = '140422814161920'
  OMP_WAIT_POLICY = 'PASSIVE'
  OMP_THREAD_LIMIT = '4294967295'
  OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS = '2147483647'
  OMP_CANCELLATION = 'FALSE'
  OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE = '0'
  OMP_MAX_TASK_PRIORITY = '0'
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT END
14 26 52 67 39 9 64 27 58 50 
9 14 26 27 39 50 52 58 64 67
```

EDIT:

```
//PARALLEL MERGE SORT
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>

void merge(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB, int end, int arrOut[]);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[]);
void parallelMergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[], int threads);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int threads, availableThreads, level=0;
    int N = 1000;
    int my_array[N];
    int outputArray[N];
    int length = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        my_array[i]=rand()%100 + 1;
    }
    //print the array 
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
    }   

    availableThreads=omp_get_max_threads();
    printf("Numero massimo di threads disponibile: %d\n", availableThreads);

    //printf("Inserisci numero di threads non superiore a %d: \n", availableThreads);
    //scanf("%d", &threads);

    //omp_set_nested(1);
    //if (omp_get_nested() != 1)
        //printf("Errore nested parallelism\n");

    int processori = omp_get_num_procs(); 
    printf("Processori: %d\n", processori);

    //if(threads>processori)
        //omp_set_num_threads(threads);

    printf("\n--------------\n");

    double start=omp_get_wtime();
    parallelMergeSort(my_array, 0, length-1, outputArray, level); 
    double end=omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Time: %f", end-start);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} 



void merge(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB, int end, int arrOut[]){
    int i=indexA, j=indexB, k=indexA;
    while(i<=indexB-1 && j<=end){
        if(arr[i]<arr[j]){
            //i=i+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        }
        else{
            //j=j+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<=indexB-1){
        //i++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=end){
        //j++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        k++;
    }
    for(i=indexA; i<=end; i++)
        arr[i]=arrOut[i];
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[]){
    int medium;
    if(inf<sup){
        medium=(inf+sup)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, inf, medium, arrOut);
        mergeSort(arr, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
        merge(arr, inf, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
    }
}

void parallelMergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[], int level){
    if (level==0){
        #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp single
        parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, sup, arrOut, 1);
    }
    else if(level<8){
        #pragma omp task shared(arr, arrOut)
        {
            parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, (inf+sup)/2, arrOut, level+1);
            parallelMergeSort(arr, (inf+sup)/2 + 1, sup, arrOut, level+1);
        }
    }
    else{
        mergeSort(arr, inf, sup, arrOut);
    }   
}
```

This is the last code. It works if I write level=8, but if I write for example level=0 or level=1 the array will not be sorted.
EDIT: If I write something different from 8 in the code, I have `Segmentation error`. Especially If I increase the number of random elements of the array. Also 1000 elements with level=8 I have this error of segmentation

Answer (score 3):

You should really not use `parallel sections` to implement a recursive merge sort as it creates a lot of nested threads (that are not reused by subsequent parallel computations). The first level creates `N` threads where `N` is the number of thread chosen by the OpenMP runtime (typically the number of hardware thread on your machine or the number of cores). Only two thread will be used to perform the merge sort. The second level creates `N*N` threads (4 thread will actually be used). The thirds `N*N*N`. This quickly creates an exponential number of thread that is much bigger than what you expect. You can limit the number of thread of a parallel section (using `num_threads(2)` here) but nested parallel sections are known not to be efficient. Consider using OpenMP **tasks** instead. However, be aware that variables used by task are `firstprivate` by default while the one of parallel sections are `shared` by default.

The code should look like this (untested):

```c
void parallelMergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[], int level){
    if (level == 0){ /* Initialization of the OpenMP parallel context */
        #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp single
        parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, sup, arrOut, 1);
    }
    else if(level <= THRESHOLD){ /* Parallel recursion with tasks */
        #pragma omp task shared(arr, arrOut)
        parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, (inf+sup)/2, arrOut, level+1);

        /* There is no need to create a task for this one as it should recursively create new one or directly compute the array */
        parallelMergeSort(arr, (inf+sup)/2 + 1, sup, arrOut, level+1);
    }
    else { /* Leaf computation */
        mergeSort(arr, inf, sup, arrOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going to try. But before trying, what is THRESHOLD? What value I have to write there? And then, when I call the function inside the main, I have to pass 0 as number of levels? `parallelMergeSort(my_array, 0, length-1, outputArray, 0)`

Comment: I have tried just now using the code you have written and in the main `parallelMergeSort(my_array, 0, length-1, outputArray, 0); ` but I have always the same error

Comment: The recursive `parallelMergeSort` calls form a (nearly) balanced binary tree. `level` is the distance from the root node to the current call node (the first call should be done with `level` set to 0. The number of created tasks should be approximately `pow(2, THRESHOLD)`. `THRESHOLD` is a variable used to define from which `level` the code stop creating new task. Generally, it is good to create more tasks than the number of OMP threads but no too much (tasks are expensive). A quite good value for `THRESHOLD` should be `(int)(log2(Nthread*8))` (so each thread should have about 4~8 tasks).

Comment: Generally, such an error appears when a library try to create too many threads or processes. It would help to know where the error appears. Can you try to remove OpenMP `omp_xxx` calls in the main function and run the program again? If there is still the problem, can you try with a simple hello-world OpenMP program? Note that you can use the environment variable `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE` to get useful runtime infos. If there is still the problem you can try to desperately reboot the machine (your OS may be in an inconsistent state) and/or reinstall GCC. By the way, how big is `N` in practice?

Comment: I removed all the omp lines from the main. The algorithm seems working now. The array is sorted as you can see in the edited post. However, what is the problem in what I was doing before?

Comment: I guess this could be because of `omp_set_nested`/`omp_get_nested`. Note that this function has been deprecated (and as I said in the answer nesting should be really avoided more generally). I would be surprised if `omp_set_num_threads` would fail unless the input is `<=0` or pretty big. I think it should be a good idea to print it so to be 100% sure. By the way, setting the number of thread is generally not great. It is better to let the user control this by the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable if possible.

Comment: What I have to print? I have not understood. Moreover, basically, do you suggest that the code in the edited post is now ok? (I have written the updated code at the bottom of the post)

Comment: Also note that if I write level=0 or level=1 it does not sort the array. If I write level=8 it works