# Generate a Random Number between 1 and N-1

Tags: c, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a random number from within a range - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c)

How would you generate a random number between 1 and N-1 where N is a number the user punches in?

So far, my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int number = 0; //number variable
    printf("This program will ask you for a number, an integer, and will print out a    random number from the range of your number 1, to N-1.");//output that explains the program's purpose and use to the user.
    //gets the input
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &number); //gets the input and stores it into variable number

    return (0);
```

}

Comment: tip: look for a function that return a random number and use a modulus operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
unsigned int
randomr(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
       double x= (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;

       return (max - min +1)*x+ min;
}
```

Check out this link:- http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the referece for random.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

you can use

num= rand() % n + 1;

Comment: simple and clean. I like it

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how "random" you want your numbers to be, you can use `rand()` function from the standard libc. This function will generate numbers between 0 and RAND_MAX. You can then get the result in the good range by using a modulo operation.

Note that this generator (a LCG) is **neither** suitable for cryptographic applications **nor** scientific applications.

If you want more suitable generators, have a look at generators such as Mersenne Twister (still not cryptosecure though).

Comment: `NOT suitable for cryptographic applications nor scientific applications` From the looks of the question and context I don't think we have to worry about that. ;)

Comment: Sure, but that's just in case someone would use this answer for something else :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [rand](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?srand%203). Bit of maths and you have a solution.