# Restrict random number generation to a range using <random>

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm generating random numbers in C++11. When I run my code

```
using namespace std;

static std::mt19937_64 rng;

int main() {
rng.seed(11);

    std::cout << rng() << std::endl;
}
```

It returns random numbers. However, I would like to restrict this to a range of numbers, say 1-1000. How would I do this, using the new `<random>` file/library introduced in C++11?

Comment: use the mod operator `%`

Comment: If you want them uniformly distributed, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution.

Comment: @andre Nope, the modulus operator doesn't generate a uniform distribution of numbers, check it out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2509679/2417578) -- noting that it's a different language, so _not_ a dup (although those answers would do just fine).

Comment: `%` is strictly speaking not correct, to see that, assume the complete range was [0, 100) if you would `% 80` random numbers from this range,  the result would no longer be uniformly distributed.

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio the documentation says its not uniform, then goes right along with the sample using it.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: It shows the sample, then explains why you shouldn't use it if you want a uniform distribution, and says "C++ supports a wide range of powerful tools to generate random and pseudo-random numbers (see <random> for more info)." If you follow the link to `<random>`, it gives you the right answer immediately.

Comment: @abarnert is there a standard library solution for C?

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio I was aware that it was not truly uniform and it was worse the larger the number was. However, I was not aware we had a better option `std::uniform_int_distribution`, thanks.

Comment: @andre Great! Glad to help, if I did.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: No, C99 only has `rand()` (POSIX adds `rand_r`, and `random`, but neither of those helps); you will need to go outside the stdlib to do it. There's a linked answer on the right, and plenty of other answers on SO and google, or you can download a PRNG library.

Comment: @JustinMeiners, There's a good question on that here. Just keep generating random numbers until they fall into the range of equally-likely ones, i.e., not the top X numbers that can cause bias.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `std::uniform_int_distribution` from `<random>`.

Example:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(1, 1000);

    std::cout << dis(gen) << '\n';
}
```

The `<random>` header includes a lot of other distributions that you can use. You can check it out [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: +1 for easily accommodating other types of distributions, unlike the thinking process that went into my comment.

Comment: Wow, thanks the code and everything!

Comment: Also, how would I store this random number as a variable?

Comment: @user2581872: `int variable = dis(gen);`

Comment: @user2581872 Like any other variable. In this case it's an `int`, so `int stuff = dis(gen);`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'm just learning how to use C++11.

Comment: Last question, how would I get multiple numbers? It gives me an error with multiple initilizations when I copy the code.

Comment: @user2581872 I don't get any errors. You might want to make that a separate question.

Comment: @user2581872: Call it multiple times: `foo = dis(gen); bar = dis(gen);`