# rand() function in with probability in chossing IP's

Tags: c

Hi I'm working on a project in c

I have 3 IPs and every IP has a weight, I want to return the IP's according to its weights
using the random function,,,, for example if we have 3 IP's : X with weight 6,Y with weight 4 and Z with weight 2, I want to return X in 50% of cases and Y in 33% of cases and Z in 17% of cases, depending on random function in C.

could any one help me with this please ?

Comment: Not that it really matters to the question, but what is an "IP"?

Comment: @KeithThompson - Internet Protocol

Comment: @EdHeal: Internet Protocol what? Address? Version of the specification? How do you know that's what the OP meant?

Comment: @KeithThompson - I guessed that it was the IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a random between 0 and 1000000 for example.
Then check, if it's smaller then 500000 then choose x, if its between 500000 and 830000 choose y and if its between 830000 and 1000000 choose z.

Answer (score 0):

```
double r = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
double denom = 6 + 4 + 2;
if (r < 6 / denom) {
  // choose X
} else if (r < (6 + 4) / denom) {
  // choose Y
} else {
  // choose Z
}
```

I've written it in a manner that should make it clear how to generalize the method.

Comment: Isn't using larger values advised? I fear that in a small range the probability for the values will not be equal, am i wrong?

Comment: You are wrong. The size of the values involved does not affect the results in this function.

Comment: In theory, but any one way function you use, (give it inputs from MIN to MAX), and you will see that not all values are reached, and there is usually a lot more values around the middle of the range.
now i don't know how rand is implemented but what makes you so sure that their probability is the same?

Comment: @TomF: I don't know why you'd think that. Where do one way functions come in? And why wouldn't all values be reached? What would cause a bias towards the middle of the range?

Comment: What is RAND_MAX means?

Comment: Sidenote: RAND_MAX is guaranteed by POSIX (?) to be _at least_ 32K.

Comment: I have tried it and it keeps go to the third section "choose z", I think that the rand() function always returns the same value over and over why ??? and how can I get over this ??

Comment: @user2683768: Edit your question to show the code you are using. You are probably making a simple mistake like not calling `srand` or using `srand` incorrectly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c

The answer there explains preetty much what i meant.