# generate random characters in c

Tags: c, random, character

I'm new to programming in C and have been given the task of creating a 2D array that stores random letters from A-Z using the random () function. I know how to do random numbers.

```
nextvalue = random ( ) % 10001;
```

but am unsure on how exactly to create a random character. I know that you can use ASCII to create a random character using the range 65 - 90 in the ASCII table. Can anyone help me come up with a solution? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should assume something about the character encoding of your system. Let's suppose it is [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and let us restrict ourselves to the 26 upper-case letters *ABC...XYZ* of the latin alphabet.

Then you could code:

```
 char randomletter = 'A' + (random() % 26);
```

This won't work on [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). You could also try

```
 char randomletter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random () % 26];
```

which would work with any encoding (including *EBCDIC*, *ASCII*, *UTF-8*, *ISO-Latin-1*) ....where each *A...Z* letter is encoded by a single `char`.

<sup>But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852396/841108) is an interesting answer explaining why `random() % 26` is wrong. In my naive non-expert view, it is good enough.</sup>

Replacing `random() % 26` by `myrandomlt26()` where we have defined

```
static inline unsigned myrandomlt26() {
   long l;
   do { l = random(); } while (l>=(RAND_MAX/26)*26);
   return (unsigned)(l % 26);
}
```

should be slightly better (Very often the `do`...`while` loop above should run once).

However, learn more e.g. about [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), you'll discover that there are some human languages where the very notion of letter (or upper-case) is not as trivial as you believe.

I'm not an expert on these matters, but urban legend says that strangely the French `œ` is not a letter (but just a ligature) because the French representative at some ISO meeting was sick when it was discussed. At French school, I recall having learned (probably in 1966-1972) that it is not a letter (but not hand-writing the ligature -which has a special name *"E dans l'O"* in French- was a spelling mistake), but some people believe the opposite. Usually accented letters like `é` or `à` are considered letters in French (but their UTF-8 encoding takes *several* consecutive `char`....).  Likewise I believe and have learned that the cyrillic [soft-sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign) `ь` is *not* a letter, even if it looks like one. Defining what is a letter in [arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet), [hebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_language), [korean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language), [cherokee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherokee_language), [thai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_language) ... should also be fun and matter of endless debates...

Comment: The second alternative is awesomer than the first, since it's portable *and* uses array indexing on a string literal which is always fun.

Comment: Yes `random() % 26` doesn't give an evenly distributed result.  However, assuming `RAND_MAX` is 2147483647, the numbers 0 - 23 have one extra chance of getting picked but the bias is pretty small.  The bigger problem is if there is some hidden cycle in the sequence that is exposed by modding by 2 or 13.  On my computer the documentation says no.

Comment: @JeremyP: Out of curiosity, what is your system, and which documentation are you talking about?

Comment: OS X.  The man page for random(3) says: "rand(3) produces a much less random sequence -- in fact, the low dozen bits generated by rand go through a cyclic pattern.  All of the bits generated by random() are usable.  For example, `random()&01` will produce a random binary value."

Comment: `warning: implicit declaration of function 'random' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already solved this problem. You just need to think harder and tinker more with it. 
In C you can easily display any ASCII character in Dec form. 
Here is the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference. 
For example

```
char c = 65;
char c = 'A'; // Both are the same thing.
```

So it is probably the same as generating a random number between 65 and 90. Hope this helps ;) Am also new to C with some background in C++.