# Convert int to char (ASCII value)

Tags: c++, ascii

I am trying to convert an `int` to a `char` using the ASCII value. The `int` is randomly generated between `97` and `122` (from `a` to `z`).

How can I generate a random number between 97 and 122 and convert it to a char?

I searched many answers before asking my question, but none solved the problem or was completely related to my need. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724346/generate-random-characters-in-c) didn't work.

Here is what I'm trying to do: in a for loop, the program generates a random number and converts it to an `int`. This is converted to its ASCII value and then placed into a `QString`. When the for loop is finished, I send the `QString` to a `line_edit`.

By following the above link, I only got an `m`.

Here's my code:

```
QString str;
int maxlenght = 16; //the user will be able to set himself the maxlenght
for (int i =0; i<maxlenght; i++)
{
    int random = 97 + (rand() % (int)122-97+1);
    char letter = (char)random;
    if(i > 0)
    {
        str[i] = letter;
    }
}
```

And though the random number is generated in the loop, it always gives me the same char.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724346/generate-random-characters-in-c

Comment: I searched an answer to my question before but didn't found this one. Thanks, will try it.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work the way i wished.

Comment: You should not tag a question both [C] and [C++].  They are different languages.

Comment: Ok i solvec one problem. But it should give me only lowercase char between a and z. so why do I get uppercase letter or '.', '^', and some other special char?

Comment: Yes, sorry @abelenky. Just because these are similar and my question can be solved both for C and C++. Is there a way to modify it?

Comment: Use `'a'`, `'z'`, instead of magic numbers 97, 122.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert string to QString after that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str="";
    int maxlenght = 16; //the user will be able to set himself the maxlenght
    for (int i =0; i<maxlenght; i++)
    {
        int rand_num = 97 + (rand() % (122 - 97 + 1));
        char letter = static_cast<char>(rand_num);
        str += letter;
    }
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of  casting `(int)(122 - 97 + 1)`? (also why aren't you just using the actual result of this calculation?)

Comment: @UnholySheep It demonstrates the range [97,122] that the random number will be generated, as requested by the OP. U can replace it by the actual value of 26 but the readers may not understand where that number comes from.

Comment: The cast is still pointless (and not even "proper" C++, use `static_cast` instead)

Comment: the range is between  97 and 122m so why do I get uppercase letter or '.', '^', and some other special char?

Comment: @Newokmyne : it is because you forgot the parenthesis around (122-97+1)

Comment: @UnholySheep: u r rite. We don't need that cast. Code updated.

Comment: Ah yes right... Thank you ^^ (I upvoted your reply by the way)