# Weird result from random character generator in C

Tags: c, random, char, printf, undefined-behavior

I am trying to write a program in C that spits out random characters. Following instructions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724403/3651337), I wrote this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void) {
   srandom((unsigned) time(NULL));
   printf("Tests various aspects of random\n");
   char misc;
   int num, index;
   printf("Enter number of chars: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   printf("\n");

   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      index = random() % 26;
      misc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[index];
      printf("%d:%s\n", index, &misc);
   }
}
```

However, it doesn't behave as I expect. When entering a small number of characters for it to generate, like 10, it makes the expected output.

My expected output is a set of

```
rand_int:char
```

pairs printed to the screen.

Here is an example of normal operation

```
Tests various aspects of random
Enter number of chars: 
7:H

4:E

23:X

2:C

4:E

17:R

22:W

11:L

9:J

4:E
```

However, if I input a large value such as 100, it outputs very strange things like:

```
Tests various aspects of random
Enter number of chars: 
18:Sd
3:Dd
21:Vd
10:Kd
19:Td
19:Td
14:Od
7:Hd
15:Pd
22:Wd
24:Yd
22:Wd
12:Md
[rest omitted for brevity...]
```

So the question is, why does it behave this way?
What might be a better approach to avoid this?

Comment: `printf("%d:%s\n", index, &misc);` -> `printf("%d:%c\n", index, misc);`

Comment: `misc` is a `char`, not a string. Using `%s` to print it you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Anyone besides me thinks that this should be closed because of simple typographical error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is very simple. The program has undefined behavior. You are using the format string `%s` that is used to output strings.

```
printf("%d:%s\n", index, &misc);
```

However the variable `misc` is not a character array that contains a string. It is just a single character. So the function `printf`  outputs all characters beyond the variable `misc` until a zero-terminating character is encountered.

And it seems that the variable `num` is allocated next to the variable misc. So the printf call outputs also bytes of the variable `num` that contains the value 100.  If to output this value stored in a byte as an ASCII  character then you will get the character `'d'`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char c = 100;

    putchar( c );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
d
```

Instead of the format `%s` use the format `%c` in the printf call. For example

```
printf("%d:%c\n", index, misc);
```

Comment: You might want to print a new-line after the putchar() call.

Answer (score 6):

The comments made by Jabberwocky and Federico klez Culloca got it right.
I was trying to print the character as a string. This was wrong and did weird things. 
I needed to use:

```
printf("%d:%c\n", index, misc);
```

instead of

```
printf("%d:%s\n", index, &misc);
```