# Random numbers with particular range

Tags: c, random

Using C Language:

- How can I generate random numbers in the [pi, 2pi] range?
- How can I generate random numbers in the [-1, 0] range?

Comment: Did you read documentation for rand()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number from within a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range)

Comment: I have read the documentation of rand(). I think that the answer of the second quastion is `x = rand()/RAN_MAX -1`, but I don't know how to implement the range [pi, 2pi].

Answer (score 1):

This is a ***pseudo*** random integer generator, but has only been tested for positive numbers, you would have to modify it to use with negatives:

```
int randomGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random=0, trying=0;

    trying = 1;         
    srand(clock());
    while(trying)
    {
        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        (random >= min) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }

    return random;
}
```

***EDIT*** (last method did not produce randoms due to `srand()` not being updated enough)

***For a range*** spanning positive and negative numbers you *could* modify it like this: (but ratio of pos to neg would be same)

```
int randomGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random=0, trying=0;
    int i=0;

    trying = 1;

    srand(clock());
    while(trying)
    {

        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        (random >= min) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }

    return (i++%2==0)?(random):(-1*random);
}
```