# Generate random number in C within a range and a specific step

Tags: c, random

OK, most probably it will be marked as duplicated, but I am looking for an answer and cannot find something similar. 
The question is: I want to generate random numbers within a specific range [i.e. min_value to max_value] and with a specific step. For the first part the answer is:

```
int random_value = rand() % max_value + min_value;
```

The step how can I define it? I suppose that the above mentioned solution results in step 1. Correct? And if for example I want to generate the numbers with step 2 (e.g. 2, 4, ..., 16) what should I do?

Comment: Multiply `rand()` by `step`?

Comment: Better tell us what do you want to accomplish, because this seems like an xy problem.

Comment: Stefano Sanfilippo by multiplication you are loosing the minimum value

Comment: does step means that value is divisible be step

Comment: Unicell I am not sure what I am not explaining well. I have a number of possible values for some parameters of my program. One parameter for example may take the values from 0 to 9 with step one and another one from 24 to 44 with step 2. In each iteration I want to pick the parameter values randomly. The first one is easy. The second one it confuses me.

Comment: Just divide the min and max by the step, choose a random number between these two (equivalent to having a step of one), and at the end multiply the result by the step to have a value between your initial min and max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
int GetRandom(int max_value, int min_value, int step)
{
    int random_value = (rand() % ((++max_value - min_value) / step)) * step + min_value;
    return random_value;
}
```

Comment: This works, but it excludes the max_value. If for example I want the values to be from 24 to 44 with step 2, the 44 is not included. I know that it is easy to solve it (define 46 instead of 44), but it would be confusing.

Comment: Ok, now you are missing a bracket

Comment: @kat you should simply be able to increment maxvalue first actually.

Comment: Yes, this is an option. Thank you Vality.

Comment: This generates random numbers that are biased. For some values the bias will be quite noticable. See: [How to generate a random number from within a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range/6852396?s=1|0.0000#6852396)

Comment: @NisseEngström You are indeed right, however I am assuming that from the OPs usage of rand already that they do not require a uniform distribution. Or at least that the level of uniformity and size of the numbers is such that it suits their requirements.

Comment: If `(++max_value - min_value)` is not a multiple of `step`, bias occurs in addition to that mentioned by @Nisse Engström.  But then OP is not clear on the requirements in that case.

Comment: @chux In this case yes it is a multiple of the step. So you have already given a solution to my problem. Now about the bias, and what Nisse and Clifford say... I think I'll go to the kitchen to wash some dishes. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your "first step" is ill-advised since it suffers from [modulo bias](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx).

Introducing a "step" is a matter of simple arithmetic, you generate a random number on a smaller range `min_value / step` to `max_value / step` and multiply that by your required step (`random_value * step`).

So:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int random_range( int min_value, int max_value )
{
    // Fix me
    return rand() % max_value + min_value;
}

int random_range_step(  int min_value, int max_value, int step )
{
    return random_range( min_value / step, max_value / step ) * step ;
}

...

//  (e.g. 2, 4, ..., 16)
int random_value = random_range_step( 2, 16, 2 ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you Clifford for your help.

Comment: You have replaced the modulo operator with the division operator. This does not get rid of the bias, as the article you linked to will explain.

Comment: @NisseEngström : I was careless with that. I have changed the solution to use the `rand()/RAND_MAX` quotient, but rearranged to avoid floating point and using a larger type for the intermediate value so it will work for the full RAND_MAX range.  Also fixed range for min to max *inclusive*.  It is simpler than the solutions suggested in the link, and what I had intended.

Comment: Confident there is an off-by-one problem.  Consider `random_range(0, RAND_MAX)`.  Code should be `.../(RAND_MAX+1)` rather than `.../RAND_MAX`.

Comment: You've managed to spread the bias over the whole range. Let's assume, for the sake of simplicity, that `RAND_MAX == 65535`, and examine how `random_range(0, 49999)` causes each of the `rand()` return values to fall into the 50000 "buckets": **bucket[0]: 2** values, **buckets[1-2]: 1** value each, **bucket[3]: 2** values, and so on. That's an astonishing bias!

Comment: @NisseEngström  As it is not really part of the question and is probably a distraction, I have left it as a note and used the original flawed code for simplicity. (i.e. I gave up! Solutions are well documented elsewhere).