# How to generate random number within x-y range, if x and y values varies [language C]

Tags: c, random

How to generate random number within x-y range in C
where

```
X : [t , t+m] and Y : [r , r+m ].
```

That is , ***if x varies from t to t+n and y varies from r to r+n.***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range

Comment: @Mike Disagree that the post is a good duplicate as that one is about integers and this is FP - subtle difference, even though the over-all math is the same.  Likely a dupe exist elsewhere though.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. It seems to be similar but it is different. Don't just go on title please read the question carefully before adding wrong links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   double x = 1.0;
   double y = 2.0;
   srand(time(NULL));

   // Guarenateed keep x1 between x and y.
   double x1 = x + rand()*(y-x)/RAND_MAX;

   printf("x1: %lf\n", x1);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you seed the generator with operation system ticks count, modulo your generated number with the upper range and add the lower range to the result.

Comment: That is not correct. For a range *x...y*, it will generate numbers between *x* and *x+y*.

Comment: @RomanAmbinder no, you modulo the random number with `(upper - lower + 1)` then add `lower`.

Comment: @Weather Vane the +1 suggested in `(upper - lower + 1)` does not quite apply to this OP's need as this code works with a FP range.  In any case, modulo on OP's range 0.0 to 0.33333 is problematic.

Comment: @chux that's true, but I commented on this answer not on the question.