# Breaking down code into header and implementation files c++

Tags: c++, xcode, header-files

I am trying to break the following code up into separate header and implementation files in C++:

```
class randomInteger {
  public:
       unsigned int operator () (unsigned int);
} randomizer;
unsigned int randomInteger::operator () (unsigned int max)
{
  // rand return random integer
  // convert to unsigned to make positive
  // take remainder to put in range
  unsigned int rval = rand();
  return rval % max;
}
unsigned int randBetween(int low, int high) {
  return low + randomizer(high - low);
}
```

Here is what I have split apart:
RandomInteger.h

```
#ifndef __EventSimulation__RandomInteger__
#define __EventSimulation__RandomInteger__

#include <iostream>

class RandomInteger {
public:
    // MEMBERS
    unsigned int operator () (unsigned int);
    unsigned int randBetween(int low, int high);
} randomizer;

#endif
```

RandomInteger.cpp

```
#include "RandomInteger.h"

unsigned int RandomInteger::operator () (unsigned int max) {
    // rand return random integer
    // convert to unsigned to make positive
    // take remainder to put in range
    unsigned int rval = rand();
    return rval % max;
}

unsigned int RandomInteger::randBetween(int low, int high) {
    return low + RandomInteger(high - low);
}
```

When I use the class in my main method for testing and try running the program I get an error " linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) " using Xcode.

Here is my simple main method:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // Test Randomized
    // Create a random number between 2 and 4
    int randomBeer = randomizer.randBetween(2, 4);

    // Switch to print beer
    cout << "BeerType: " << randomBeer << endl;
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the error:
[image]

Comment: `class RandomInteger {...} randomizer;` declares a class *and* defines a variable. If you split this into two, it might become clearer.

Comment: Also, what other errors did you get? The linker should have printed a message before failing.

Comment: Did you compile both `.cpp` files?

Answer (score 1):

Two notes here:

1. In *RandomInteger.h* file you define a randomizer variable and I believe you need to do this in source file;
2. By writing `RandomInteger(high - low);` I think you want to call `operator () (unsigned int)` but instead you're trying to create an object like `RandomInteger::RandomInteger(int)`. I don't think you have such constructor. Otherwise *randomizer* object won't be created (using default one without parameters).

Answer (score 0):

In the first, unsplit version, you define a class and an instance of the class at the same time. The class has a data member and a single method. You then define a simple function, `randBetween`, that uses that instance.

When you broke it up, you still create a global instance, `randomizer`, but this time you made `randBetween` a method of `class RandomInteger`. When you migrated `randBetween`, though, you try to invoke a **constructor**, `RandomInteger(int)`, which you never defined. (It could also be trying to look for a typecast operator, but **not** `operator()`.)

Because you're creating that instance in **every** module in which you include `RandomInteger.h`, you're getting the duplicate symbol shown in your screenshot.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here, so suggesting code that will "work" would require a number of assumptions. I don't see the need for a class here, as you seem to be doing nothing more than making a class to contain a couple of functions, rather than having an object that you'll want to instantiate more than once.

I should also note here that using the `%` operator, as you're doing, will give you **unpredictable** results, but not statistically **random** results; the distribution will be poor and predictable. Consider the method used in [section 13.16 of the C Programming FAQ](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html), or some of the more complex answers [at this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range).