# Create array using a set list

Tags: c, random

I have this,

```
    srand( ( unsigned) 0 );
    for( n = 0; n < len; ++n )  
     {                          
         word[ n ] = 'a' + rand( ) % ;

     }
     word[ n ] = '\0';
```

and i need it to select the random characters from a set list of non consecutive, characters, B,H,G,K,V and fill the string with the characters selected. What I don't know how to do is get my program to select from only those few characters

Comment: what is `word[ n ] = 'a' + rand( ) % ;`?

Answer (score 2):

Generate an integer between 0 and 4 (last index of [B,H,G,K,V]).

Then use this random integer to index into an array of your characters:

```
static const char letters[] = "BHGKV"; //your letters as a string
word[n] = letters[rand() % 5]; //get a random letter from letters
```

Note, `rand() % 5` may not be the best way to [generate a random number in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range).

Comment: Note this will not generate an uniform distribution if `(RAND_MAX + 1) % 5 != 0` Sidenote: why not use a string literal, but an `int`?

Comment: @Olaf Yep, indeed. But what about the missing operand after `%` in OP's code? Did you notice?

Comment: why do you use the `floor` function? it is a no-op in the best case and will create problems if the `double` value of an integer is smaller than the `int` itself.

Comment: @mch because I'm a C newbie. My code is more pseudo than actual. What is the proper way to floor an `int` in C? (Just looked it up, I will change to an `int` cast.)

Comment: As `floor()` rounds a float to the next lower `int`: what do you want and`int` to be rounded to? Note: `rand()` already returns an `int`.

Comment: @Olaf thank you. Ah my I assumed it was analogous to the Java Math.random(). Think my code should be C-worthy now.

Comment: Well, I would make `letters` `static const` so it will not be created/copied on each call. And there is still the issue with non-uniform distribution. Albeit I would not care too much for this question:-} and as you added a link to that, it looks ok to me.