# Random number between INT_MAX & INT_MIN

Tags: c, random

Well I feel my question is bit more complex compared to other questions.
I realized this while trying to solve it.

I tried using

```
int number = rand() % (INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1) + INT_MIN;
rand() % (INT_MAX + INT_MIN + 1) + rand() % INT_MIN;
```

However, I got floating point exception 8 error. No warnings, that's really strange!

Also, from `time.h`, I used `srand((unsigned)time(NULL))` for new random number every time I execute my code.

But whatever I try either I get incorrect results or floating point exception.

I am really curious as to overflow & underflow, how it's happening and
can such a random number be actually generated?

I basically want to generate a number in C greater than `INT_MIN` and lesser than `INT_MAX`.

I tried lots of logic but I got incorrect result.

Comment: Please let me know what is wrong with my post. I have just begun to learn C programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number from within a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range)

Comment: Two issues with your post: 1. The answer is easy to find with a simple Google search. 2. SHOUTING IN THE TITLE.

Comment: I tried that solution before posting my question.

Comment: I am really sorry. I googled but always I am going wrong. Maybe I am novice to C right now.

Comment: I have a feeling that `(INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1)` is equal to 0. BTW, I DIDN'T DOWN VOTE, BUT THE CAPS, and the yellow text are probably annoying to some people.

Comment: Novice or not, you've got to learn to use a debugger. In your case I'd break the computation into pieces and see what those pieces produce. For instance I feel the `(INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1)` is going to overflow right there.

Comment: Honestly, I tried past 2 days using netbeans on mac , code signing didn't work. Installed gdb & Xcode but Xcode removed C debugging features too.The moment I click debugger in netbeans , it freezes.I am on Yosemite on Retina macbook pro 13" (haskell version). I strangely enough cannot change color to anything else , tried editing it stays yellow :(

Comment: @John3136 A careful read of the suggested duplicate indicates a question and answers that focuses on a significant sub-range of `int` and not its entire range.  Even the top rated answer requires `0 <= max <= RAND_MAX` which does not meet this post's `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]` requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`(INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1)` is probably going to overflow (since they're `int` literals) and produce 0, explaining your error (you're dividing by 0).

Changing to `((long)INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1)` would avoid the overflow (assuming `long` is bigger than `int`, which is not the case for Visual Studio on Windows, where you'd need to cast to `long long`).

That said, you're not going to get the results you want with a single `rand` call; it only produces numbers between 0 and `RAND_MAX`; `RAND_MAX` is usually 32767, so you'd end up covering only a trivial portion of the possible range for `int` on most systems (where `int` is usually 32 bits).

To make this work, you'd need to generate enough bits to fill an int. Something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Assumes srand() has been called with an appropriate seed at some point
   Code assumes C99 is available; minor tweaks needed for older compilers.
 */
int gen_random_int() {
    const int BITS_PER_RAND = (int)(log2(RAND_MAX/2 + 1) + 1.0); /* Or log(RAND_MAX + 1) / log(2) with older language standards */
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i += BITS_PER_RAND) {
        ret <<= BITS_PER_RAND;
        ret |= rand();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You don't even need to bother with `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, because this fills in an `int` directly; the excess bits of random generated overflow and get discarded.

Comment: `INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1ULL` would be cleaner as no cast is needed

Comment: OOC, does the standard actually guarantee it would be evaluated in that order? If `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` is evaluated first, you've already overflowed. I know expanding the left side value involved in the overflowing calculation will work, but I'm not confident that expanding the `1` wouldn't invoke implementation specific behavior.

Comment: In the same expression, the common type will be used no matter what order they're evaluated in

Comment: Well I think it causes overflow since I get floating point error .In fact in any order I do INT_MAX - INT_MIN , I am guaranteed that error . Tried that function, compiler throws "error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant static const int BITS_PER_RAND = (int)log2(RAND_MAX + 1); /* Or log(RAND_MAX + 1) / log(2) with older language standards */"

Comment: @user2285161: Without an upcast of some sort (implicit as Lưu describes or explicit as my answer mentions), you'd overflow. The overflow doesn't directly cause the exception though; the exception is because the resulting 0 is used for division, and dividing (remainder operations are equivalent to division for this purpose) by zero causes the exception you're seeing. Reasonable compilers should notice a division by a compile time constant of 0 though, so that's a little strange.

Comment: @user2285161 remove `static` from the declaration, or calculate the number of bits yourself. `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` **always** overflow because it results in **4294967295** (2^32-1), assuming 32-bit int, and that is outside of int's range. Moreover, `INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1` results in 0 (as the low 32 bits of 4294967296 is all 0) which causes the exception

Comment: Ah, sorry. My mistake on the constant. I'll fix.

Comment: It's working superb... However , just for fun , if I want to generate a number such that INT_MAX < number < INT_MIN means number can be negative also , right ? Or am I thinking way too much :)

Comment: This is filling in a signed integer and left-shifting into the sign bit, so it will generate both positive and negative numbers in the complete range from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`, inclusive on both ends (`INT_MAX` < `number` < `INT_MIN` makes no sense, because that's asking the `number` to be greater than a huge positive number and less than a huge negative number). I can't be 100% sure it will work as expected on truly bizarre architectures, but on your standard two's complement (or one's complement for that matter) architecture, the unsigned values still produce signed outputs.

Comment: `RAND_MAX + 1` in `log2(RAND_MAX + 1)` may `int` overflow --> UB.  Alternative:  `(log2(RAND_MAX/2 + 1) + 1.0)`.

Comment: `ret <<= BITS_PER_RAND;` is also subject to `int` overflow (UB).

Comment: @chux: True on both counts. I incorporated your suggested fix for `RAND_MAX + 1` overflowing, if you have suggestions for fully defined ways to populate the `int` I'm open to them (in practice I've never seen overflow misbehave in this case, but my experience is obviously not exhaustive, nor normative).

Answer (score 1):

`INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1` is `int` overflow and therefore undefined behavior.

The behavior your system experienced was a divide by 0 as that is often, though not specified, result of `INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1` --> `0`.

`rand()` generates an `int` in the range `[0...RAND_MAX]`.  Since `RAND_MAX <= INT_MAX`, it could take multiple calls to construct an `int` in the range `[0...INT_MAX]` let alone in your quest of `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`.

Below is a generic approach.  It is not highly efficient but simple and obviously amendable for all sorts of types.

```
int rand_int(void) {
  union {
    int i;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof (int)];
  } u;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof u.uc; i++) {
    u.uc[i] = rand();
  }
  return u.i;
}
```

It technically can cause UB on rare machines that have a trap value for `int`.

Comment: I created a custom formula and finally I am able to generate a number both positive and negative between INT_MAX & INT_MIN. :) Thanks for the suggestions. They are really so precious for me ! :)

Comment: Random functions have many pitfalls. Suggest posting your solution here as an answer or for review at `http://codereview.stackexchange.com`