# There is an error that I don't know

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char names[10][10], name[10], gender;
    printf("Welcome to Autumn sim");
    names = ["Nathan", "August", "Bob", "Joe", "Stewart", "Martha", "Tiffany", "Darlene", "Kate", "Sophie"];

    printf("What is your gender? m or f?\n");
    scanf("%c", &gender);
    if (gender == "m" || "M")
    {
        name = names[rand(0, 4)][10];
    }
    else if (gender == "F" || "f")
    {
        name = names[rand(5, 9)][10];
    }

    printf("Your name is...");
    printf("Loading");

    printf("%s", name);
    return 0;

}
```

This is my program. I am trying to ask gender and randomly give their name. There are five names if they are male and other five names if they are female. But it keep saying
!expression must be identifiable 1 value!
which I cannot understand. please somebody help me!!!
Also, I want to know how to wait in c, I want to wait after "Loading".

Comment: There are many basic issues in your code. C is not Python. You are probably better off reading a proper text book on C.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has no understanding of the underlying principals of the language that s/he is attempting to write in

Answer (score 2):

You can not *assign* to an array, only copy to it. *Or* initialize it when you define the array.

The simple solution is to initialize the array:

```
char names[10][10] = {
    "Nathan", "August", "Bob", "Joe", "Stewart",
    "Martha", "Tiffany", "Darlene", "Kate", "Sophie"
};
```

You also have a problem with your comparison for e.g. `gender`. The variable `gender` is a *character* and so you need to compare it with another character. And character literals are using single-quotes and not double-quotes. So the *character* `m` is `'m'` (not `"m"` which is a string).

Then the logic is wrong as well. The expression `gender == 'm' || 'M'` is actually equal to `gender == ('m' || 'M')`, meaning you compare `gender` to the result of `'m' || 'M'`. The expression `'m' || 'M'` will *always* be `1`, so the comparison will fail. You need to explicitly compare `gender` with both `'m'` and `'M'` as in `gender == 'm' || gender == 'M'`.

Or you could use the [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) function like `tolower(gender) == 'm'`.

---

To get a single name from your array of names, you have two choices. One is to keep using your array `name`, but since you can assign to an array you have to *copy* to it. To copy strings one typically uses the [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function:

```
strcpy(name, names[1]);  // Copy the second name
```

The other possibility is to use pointers, so you declare `name` as a pointer to `char`:

```
char *name;
```

Then you can make it point to any element in the `names` array:

```
name = names[1];  // Make name point to the second name
```

Which one you should use depends on what you are doing. If you just want to display the string, then either will work fine. If you want to modify the string, without modifying the strings in `names` then you should use an array.

---

Lastly there is another problem with your code. The [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) function does not work as you expect.

See e.g. [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17554531/440558) FOr how to generate a random number in a range.

Comment: Thank you, But how do you assign a name? How do you call "Nathan" out of names?

Comment: @한국인 Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

there are a lots of errors in your code...

- First you use `names` but don't specify the type.
- You compare gender, a `char` (gender) with `"m"`, and double quote means a `char *` value.
- You cannot do `if (gender == "m" || "M")`, that means if the gender is equal to "m", or if "M" have a value (is different of zero), and it is, so the condition will always be true.
- On this line : `name = names[rand(0, 4)][10];`, what is the type of `name`, and what is the type of `names[rand(0, 4)][10]` ?
- You should read the man of `rand`, you don't use it correctly.

Try to fix these issues, this should work better ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
names = ["Nathan", "August", "Bob", "Joe", "Stewart", "Martha", "Tiffany", "Darlene", "Kate", "Sophie"];
```

you cannot assign to an "array" type, and the syntax is also wrong.

you have to either

- assign element by element
- initialize the array using the brace-enclosed initializer list.

Comment: Thank you, But how do you assign a name? How do you call "Nathan" out of names?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. This is one of the way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char name[10] = "";
    char gender   = ' ';
    printf("Welcome to Autumn sim");
    char names[10][10] = ["Nathan", "August", "Bob", "Joe", "Stewart", "Martha", "Tiffany", "Darlene", "Kate", "Sophie"];

    printf("What is your gender? m or f?\n");
    scanf("%c", &gender);
    if (gender == 'm' || gender == 'M') //Compare gender with charecter ('m' OR 'f')
    {
        strcpy(name, names[rand(0, 4)]); //Copy the string
    }
    else if (gender == 'F' || gender  == 'f')
    {
        strcpy(name, names[rand(5, 9)]);
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Invalid gender entered") //Check if input is invalid
    }

    if(0 < strlen(name)) //Print only if input is valid
    {
        printf("Your name is...");
        printf("Loading");

        usleep(1000*1000*1000); //1s sleep

        printf("%s", name);
    }
    return 0;

}
```