# How to randomize a place in array

Tags: c, arrays, random, minesweeper

I'm trying to code the game Minesweeper and for that I need to randomize the bombs locations.

Can someone help change the function a bit so that placing of bombs is randomized?

THE CODE:

```
void Createbomb(int*** bord, int size)//size+1
{
    //bomb num.1
    (*bord)[size - 5][size - 1] = 9;
    //bomb num.2
    (*bord)[size - 4][size - 4] = 9;
    //bomb num.3
    (*bord)[size - 3][size - 2] = 9;
    //bomb num.4
    (*bord)[size - 2][size - 2] = 9;
    //bomb num.5
    (*bord)[size - 1][size - 5] = 9;
}
```

Comment: `rand() % size` gives you a "random" number in the range `0` till `size-1` inclusive.

Comment: @mch Not really, at least if you use the generated values for something important. If `RAND_MAX` is not divisible by `size` there will be some skewing towards the lower values.  And more importantly, many PRNGs have very poor randomness in the low order bits.  See [**Random integers in C, how bad is rand()%N compared to integer arithmetic? What are its flaws?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880304/random-integers-in-c-how-bad-is-randn-compared-to-integer-arithmetic-what-a)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the number of bombs you need is 5. Also, let initially `board` contain default value of 1 for all cells, and 9 only if there is a bomb present in the cell. Then you can do something like:

```c
void createBomb(int*** board, int size){
    srand(time(0));
    int numOfBombsPlaced = 0;
    while(numOfBombsPlaced < 5){
        int x = rand()%size;
        int y = rand()%size;
        if ((*board)[x][y]==9):
             continue;
        numOfBombsPlaced++;
        (*board)[x][y] = 9;
    }
}
```

Note that the numbers generated by `rand` are not truly random, and depend on the initial seed. The seed is provided by `srand`. Using `time` for seed is a good option to randomise.

Comment: `srand(time(0));` for ***every*** call to the function?!?!?

Comment: Since the function is called once to populate the bombs, I think it should be good to go. :/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the modulus to get a pseudo-random number, since with a few trials, we can easily figure out which is going to be the next number. There are several ways of randomize in a good way, this is one way, that is better that using the modulus:
(If you have interest, there are more complex ways to generate random numbers)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int random_num(int inf, int sup)
{
    if(inf < 0 || sup-inf < 0) return -1; /*Only positive numbers because it is an array */

    return inf+(int)(((sup-inf+1.0)*rand())/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
}
```

RAND_MAX is a constant value defined in stdlib.h, roughly speaking it is a huge integer constant, i.e, a big integer number.

So, in your program you just have to call:

```
int x = random_num(0, size); /*Gets a new random number in the desired range*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a ncurses based Minesweeper a long time ago (around 1993).  It's opensource and it's now in Github, If you want hints about how to implement some part of it, you have full source code [there](https://github.com/mojadita/buscamin).  You are free to download, clone, and even to show me better ways to implement something if you get some.

My approach was to use a matrix for the field cells, and to store on them the number of neighbour bombs, while one bit stored the presence of a bomb.  I'm afraid it was written so long ago that I have not had a time to translate all the comments and identifiers into english... but probably this is a good time to do so.... let's think on it.