# How to sort dates from an array in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort dates from an array i've got the following code (without including the array and the file that i'm trying to read and the other with the sorted dates that i'm trying to write.

```
int aniomayor=tot[0].anio;
int diamayor=tot[0].dia;
int mesmayor=tot[0].mes;

while (i<nf) {
  if (tot[i].anio > aniomayor) {
    int aniomayor=tot[i].anio;
    int diamayor=tot[i].dia;
    int mesmayor=tot[i].mes;
  }
  else if (tot[i].anio == aniomayor && tot[i].mes > mesmayor) {
    int aniomayor=tot[i].anio;
    int diamayor=tot[i].dia;
    int mesmayor=tot[i].mes;
  }
  else if (tot[i].anio == aniomayor && tot[i].mes == mesmayor &&  tot[i].dia > diamayor) {
    int aniomayor=tot[i].anio;
    int diamayor=tot[i].dia;
    int mesmayor=tot[i].mes;
  }

  i++;
}

fprintf(f, "%s ", diamayor);
fprintf(f, "%s ", mesmayor);
fprintf(f, "%s \n", aniomayor);
```

I think it would work but in the 2,3,4.. line it will print always the same date and i don't know how to do for it to ignore the dates that already had been sorted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's going on here with the repeated variable declarations inside a scope in which they will immediately fall out of scope? You should probably declare the `int` once and once only per function.

Comment: remove the `int`s before the variables in the `while` loop.  you're creating new variables in a scope, editing them, and then letting them fall out of scope.

Comment: i've removed int but i don´t know what to do next

Comment: You removed the problem that we're trying to fix.

Comment: Tip: When sorting things, use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) or something like it. Don't roll your own sorting.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with i've removed the problem i'm just trying to sort the dates

Comment: @JoseLuis someone may view this post later and not understand what we meant by "remove the `int`s".  don't edit out the problem in your post.

Comment: I've edited to restore the original problem with shadow variables. There's also a sorting problem but as I've mentioned, using `qsort` could fix that. What you're trying to do here is find out the "max" entry using a simple tie-breaker, something that `qsort` can easily handle.

Comment: will it work something like qsort(fechas, numberofarrayitems, sizeof(*fechas), idk);
but i dont know what to put in in idk

Comment: `int diamayor=tot[0].dia; ... fprintf(f, "%s ", diamayor);` --> Change `"%s "` to `"%d "`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, it is preferable to use `qsort`, (if one doesn't care about stability.) One needs a function pointer, which is `compare_dates` in the code below.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT*, rand, qsort */
#include <stdio.h>  /* *printf */
#include <time.h>   /* clock */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */

struct Date { int anio, mes, dia; };

/** Random [i, j]. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852396/2472827
 This is just used for test purposes. */
static int rand_range(const int i, const int j) {
    const unsigned long max = (unsigned long)j - i,
        num_bins = max + 1l,
        num_rand = (unsigned long)RAND_MAX + 1,
        bin_size = num_rand / num_bins,
        defect   = num_rand % num_bins;
    unsigned long x;
    assert(i <= j && num_bins <= RAND_MAX);
    do { x = 1l * rand(); } while (num_rand - defect <= x);
    return i + x / bin_size;
}

/** Initiaises the date with random. */
static void init_date(struct Date *const date) {
    assert(date);
    date->anio = rand_range(1950, 2050);
    date->mes  = rand_range(1, 12);
    date->dia  = rand_range(1, 30); /* Approximately. */
}

/** Prints the date in a static string.
 Assumes the date is sanitised, or else this presents a risk of overflow. */
static const char *print_date(const struct Date *const date) {
    static char print[128]; /* Should be 11 if -999 <= year < 9999. */
    assert(date);
    sprintf(print, "%4.4d-%2.2d-%2.2d", date->anio, date->mes, date->dia);
    return print;
}

/** The arguments must be const struct Date *.
 @return -, =, + */
static int compare_dates(const void *p, const void *q) {
    const struct Date *x = (const struct Date *)p, *y = (const struct Date *)q;
    assert(p && q);
    if(x->anio > y->anio) return 1;
    if(x->anio < y->anio) return -1;
    if(x->mes  > y->mes)  return 1;
    if(x->mes  < y->mes)  return -1;
    if(x->dia  > y->dia)  return 1;
    if(x->dia  < y->dia)  return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Date dates[64];
    const size_t dates_size = sizeof dates / sizeof *dates;
    size_t i;

    /* Generate dates. */
    srand((unsigned)clock());
    for(i = 0; i < dates_size; i++) init_date(dates + i);
    /* Sort it using compare_dates. */
    qsort(dates, dates_size, sizeof *dates, &compare_dates);
    /* Print. */
    for(i = 0; i < dates_size; i++) printf("%s.\n", print_date(dates + i));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

See [How to generate a random integer number from within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-number-from-within-a-range).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check

Comment: Aside: Using `unsigned` is usually sufficient in `rand_range()` instead of `unsigned long`.  `unsigned long` makes sense with `random()`, `unsigned` makes sense with `rand()`.

Answer (score 5):

The original `int` declaration establishes variables. The subsequent ones create "shadow" variables that have the same name but are not the same variable.

Here's a demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int x = 1;

  if (x == 1) {
    int x = 2;
    printf("x=%d\n", x);
  }

  printf("x=%d\n", x);

  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
x=2
x=1
```

The top-level `x` never gets modified, so it appears to revert to the original value.

You should remove the `int` prefix from those, just assign to the existing variable.

When you say `int x = y;` in C you are *declaring a variable* and assigning a value. To assign to an existing variable `x = y;` is sufficient.

The `int` prefix is only necessary on the first instance of the variable so the compiler knows what type to use for that and all subsequent references *inside the same scope*.

Now normally the compiler would complain about creating another variable with the same name if it's done in the same scope. In your case because you're doing it inside an `if`, technically that's a different scope so you can have duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't realiced i putted int inside while too.