# Random number generator doesn't work for me ( C language)

Tags: c, function, numbers, generator, random-seed

For example : if i choose between 0-10 , the program generate a number above 10 which is 15 or 11 or ....
How to fixt it please ?

```
int randomNumbers(int max, int min){
  int number;
  srand(time(NULL));   //change the generated number each time i run this program
  number = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
  return number;
}
void guessingnumber (){

int storednum, low, high, userGuess;

printf(" choose the lowest value : ");
scanf("%d", &low);
printf("Now, choose the highest value : ");
scanf("%d", &high);

storednum = randomNumbers(low, high);
printf("We have guessed a number between %d and %d. Guess our number : ", low, high);
scanf("%d", &userGuess);

while (userGuess != storednum){
if(userGuess \< storednum){
printf("higher: ");
scanf("%d", &userGuess);
}
else{
printf("Lower: ");
scanf("%d", &userGuess);
}
}

printf("You are correct the number was %d!", storednum);
}
```

[The result of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqPil.png)

fix the function please !!

Comment: [`srand()` - why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: Consistent indenting and formatting would make your code a lot easier to read. IDEs and programming oriented text editors, or tools like `clang-format` and GNU `indent` are great for that.

Comment: Check out [How do I get random integers in a certain range?](https://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) from the comp.lang.c FAQ or [How to generate a random integer number from within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-number-from-within-a-range) here on SO.

Comment: Hey, gold badge people! That `srand()` question isn't a dupe, but the other SO question I linked to probably is...

Comment: You aren't calling the `randomNumbers` function the way that you have designed it: `storednum = randomNumbers(low, high);` --> `storednum = randomNumbers(high, low);`, or redesign the signature so that it accepts the low number first (sensibly).