# Insertion sort - program exits with error 5

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I'm a beginner. I want to learn insertion sort, but in the printing I got an error. Running the code I got this output:

```
entrez la taille du tableau : 5
entrez les elements du tableau : 43
32
1
4
5
votre tableau ressemble a :  43  32  1  4  5 
tableau TRIE:  4  4  1  1  1
--------------------------------
Process exited after 6.303 seconds with return value 5
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void triinsertion(int T[], int taille)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < taille; i++)
    {
        int temp = T[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (temp > T[j] && j >= 0)
        {
            T[j + 1] = T[j];
            j--;
        }
        T[j] = temp;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int taille, i;
    printf("entrez la taille du tableau : ");
    scanf("%d", &taille);
    
    int T[taille];
    printf("entrez les elements du tableau : ");   
    for (i = 0; i < taille; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &T[i]);
    }
    
    printf("votre tableau ressemble a : ");
    for (i = 0; i < taille; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ", T[i]);
    }

    triinsertion(T, taille);
    
    printf("tableau TRIE: ");
    for (i = 0; i < taille; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ", T[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the problem is? Did you expect a different output? Which? When does your program deviate from expected intermediate values when you go through it step-by-step with a debugger?

Comment: Apart from that, please fix your indentaion chaos. It is distracting and making analysis harder.

Comment: i was expecting : 43 32 5 4 1 , descending order

Comment: Why do you ignore comments that ask you to properly indent your code? Also in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77628874/5459839) the indentation is off, and you got a comment about that there as well... with no action from your part...

Comment: Normally insertion sort uses two arrays, the source, and the array being inserted into. You're using one array, and overwriting existing values with the insertion (you're also not inserting properly). If you want a single array, a bubble sort would be more appropriate.

Comment: Fixed the indentation.

Comment: **NOTE:** you cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return***. E.g., `if (scanf("%d", &taille) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }` Similar for `scanf("%d", &T[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your insertion sort function:

1. The `while` condition does not check whether the index `j` is valid *before* accessing `T[j]`. It does so *after* making that access, but then it is too late. If `j` is less than 0, then accessing `T[j]` leads to undefined behaviour. This could be an error that exits your program, like happened in your example.
2. The assignment at the end is wrong: `T[j]=temp;` is assigning `temp` to the wrong index. Note that `j` could even be -1, so this makes no sense. You should assign to `T[j + 1]`.

Not a problem, but you never use the outer defined `j`, since you declare it again inside the loop block.

Here is the corrected function:

```
void triinsertion(int T[], int taille)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < taille; i++)
    {
        int temp = T[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && temp > T[j])
        {
            T[j + 1] = T[j];
            j--;
        }
        T[j + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```