# Could random.randint(1,10) ever return 11?

Tags: python, random, bounds

When researching for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036208) and reading the sourcecode in `random.py`, I started wondering whether `randrange` and `randint` really behave as "advertised". I am very much inclined to believe so, but the way I read it, `randrange` is essentially implemented as

```
start + int(random.random()*(stop-start))
```

(assuming integer values for `start` and `stop`), so `randrange(1, 10)` should return a random number between 1 and 9.

`randint(start, stop)` is calling `randrange(start, stop+1)`, thereby returning a number between 1 and 10.

My question is now:

If `random()` were ever to return `1.0`, then `randint(1,10)` would return `11`, wouldn't it?

Comment: By the way, `int(random.random() * n)` still isn't a perfect way to generate integers that are uniformly distributed in `range(n)`;  there's a bias that's insignificant for small `n` but becomes significant as `n` becomes large.  I've opened a Python bug for this at http://bugs.python.org/issue9025

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: Thanks! This is fascinating.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: [This bug is fixed as of today](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#random).

Comment: true, provided that you're using Python >= 3.2.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From `random.py` and the docs:

```
"""Get the next random number in the range [0.0, 1.0)."""
```

The `)` indicates that the interval is *exclusive* 1.0. That is, it will never return 1.0.

This is a general convention in mathematics, `[` and `]` is inclusive, while `(` and `)` is exclusive, and the two types of parenthesis can be mixed as `(a, b]` or `[a, b)`. Have a look at [wikipedia: Interval (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Excluding_the_endpoints) for a formal explanation.

Comment: I hadn't caught that `)` (and even if I had, I wouldn't have known its meaning, so thank you very much for this insightful answer).

Comment: @Tim: FYI, there exist several different conventions. Another commonly used convention is inverting the square braces, so that `[a, b[` would be a half-open interval equivalent to `[a, b)`.

Comment: This isn't quite enough, since it's not obvious that `0.0 <= x < 1.0` implies that `0 <= x * n < n` in floating-point arithmetic:  in general, the result of the multiplication won't be exactly representable, so it'll be rounded.  And it could be rounded up.  It's *conceivable* that this rounding could produce `n`, for `x` very close to (but not equal to) `1.0`.

Fortunately it's possible to show that, assuming round-to-nearest, this can never happen.

Comment: Interesting point. Same applies for other programming languages?

Comment: Sure;  this is nothing particularly special to Python.  With IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic in round-to-nearest mode,  you can show that `x * y < y` for any `x < 1.0` and any non-tiny positive `y`.  (It can fail if `y` is either subnormal or the smallest positive normal number.)

Answer (score 12):

Other answers have pointed out that the result of `random()` is always *strictly* less than `1.0`;  however, that's only half the story.

If you're computing `randrange(n)` as `int(random() * n)`, you *also* need to know that for any Python float `x` satisfying `0.0 <= x < 1.0`, and any positive integer `n`, it's true that `0.0 <= x * n < n`, so that `int(x * n)` is strictly less than `n`.

There are two things that could go wrong here:  first, when we compute `x * n`, `n` is implicitly converted to a float.  For large enough `n`, that conversion might alter the value.  But if you look at the Python source, you'll see that it only uses the `int(random() * n)` method for `n` smaller than `2**53` (here and below I'm assuming that the platform uses IEEE 754 doubles), which is the range where the conversion of `n` to a float is guaranteed not to lose information (because `n` can be represented exactly as a float).

The second thing that could go wrong is that the result of the multiplication `x * n` (which is now being performed as a product of floats, remember) probably won't be exactly representable, so there will be some rounding involved.  If `x` is close enough to `1.0`, it's conceivable that the rounding will round the result up to `n` itself.

To see that this can't happen, we only need to consider the largest possible value for `x`, which is (on almost all machines that Python runs on) `1 - 2**-53`.  So we need to show that `(1 - 2**-53) * n < n` for our positive integer `n`, since it'll always be true that `random() * n <= (1 - 2**-53) * n`.

**Proof** (Sketch) Let `k` be the unique integer `k` such that `2**(k-1) < n <= 2**k`.  Then the next float down from `n` is `n - 2**(k-53)`.  We need to show that `n*(1-2**53)` (i.e., the actual, unrounded, value of the product) is closer to `n - 2**(k-53)` than to `n`, so that it'll always be rounded down.  But a little arithmetic shows that the distance from `n*(1-2**-53)` to `n` is `2**-53 * n`, while the distance from `n*(1-2**-53)` to `n - 2**(k-53)` is `(2**k - n) * 2**-53`.  But `2**k - n < n` (because we chose `k` so that `2**(k-1) < n`), so the product *is* closer to `n - 2**(k-53)`, so it *will* get rounded down (assuming, that is, that the platform is doing some form of round-to-nearest).

So we're safe.  Phew!

---

Addendum (2015-07-04): The above assumes IEEE 754 binary64 arithmetic, with round-ties-to-even rounding mode.  On many machines, that assumption is fairly safe.  However, on x86 machines that use the x87 FPU for floating-point (for example, various flavours of 32-bit Linux), there's a possibility of [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) in the multiplication, and that makes it possible for `random() * n` to round *up* to `n` in the case where `random()` returns the largest possible value.  The smallest such `n` for which this can happen is `n = 2049`.  See the discussion at http://bugs.python.org/issue24546 for more.

Answer (score 3):

From Python documentation:

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function random(), which generates a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0).

Like almost every PRNG of float numbers..