# Can 0.99999999999 be rounded to 1.0 when multiplying?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, math, floating-point

When multiplying a floating point number that is very close to 1 with an int > 0, can it ever be interpreted as 1.

That is, if `Math.random()` returns its highest possible result (which is 1 step below 1.0), will

```
(int)(Math.random() * 8)
```

be 8 or 7?

For a practical example, can this often-used construct give an index out of bounds error:

```
someArray[(int)(Math.random() * someArray.length)];
```

I'm specifically interested in answers for Java and ActionScript 3, but I suppose they all use the same rules for floating point arithmetic, and answers for any platform would be useful.

*Update*: Though I already accepted an answer, I'd still appreciate confirmation that this can't go wrong in ActionScript 3 either, since a colleague reporting that he saw it go wrong once is what partly prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if such a number *never* overflowed into the next int... but I'll wait for a better answer...

Comment: @UdoFholl I didn't intend to use any official mathematical notation, just wanted to indicate a number with many many nines.

Comment: *When multiplying a floating number that is very close to 1, can it ever be interpreted as 1* -- Yes, if you multiply it by 0 ;-) JK

Comment: simply, add IF statement to avoid this situation :)

Comment: @JoshLee: Mathematically, 0.99999999999999999999999... is the same number as 1.0, but a computer can't represent 0.9999999999999999999999999... in a float or double, which (among other things) makes it impossible for a random number generator to generate it.

Comment: @cHao I’m talking about the terminating decimal 0.9999999999999999999999. The nearest approximation as a float or double *is* 1.0.

Comment: @Josh: Irrelevant, though, since a RNG (being a computer program) won't generate numbers a computer can't represent exactly.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you multiply the greatest value below 1.0 with `someInt` (> 0), the result will never be `someInt`.

This can be exhaustively tested for integers like this:

```
Double greatestLessThanOne = Double.longBitsToDouble(4607182418800017407L);

// Assert that greatestLessThanOne is indeed the largest double less than 1.
//assert 1.0 == greatestLessThanOne + Math.ulp(greatestLessThanOne);

for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i++)
    if ((int) (greatestLessThanOne * i) == i)
        System.out.println("Exception found: " + i);
```

The snippet produces no output.

([`Math.ulp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29) returns the distance between the given double and the double value next larger in magnitude. The assertion thus ensures that `greatestLessThanOne` is indeed the greatest value less than 1.0.)

In other words, your line

```
Object element = elementArray[(int)(Math.random() * elementArray.length)];
```

will never give rise to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

---

Furthermore, according to Mark Dickinsons comment over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037952/could-random-randint1-10-ever-return-11/3037976#3037976), this holds also when multiplying with a double.

> With IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic in round-to-nearest mode, you can show that `x * y <` y for any `x < 1.0` and any non-tiny positive `y`. (It can fail if `y` is either subnormal or the smallest positive normal number.)

Comment: Good answer.  And [Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html) uses round-to-nearest: "The Java programming language requires that floating-point arithmetic behave as if every floating-point operator rounded its floating-point result to the result precision. Inexact results must be rounded to the representable value nearest to the infinitely precise result; if the two nearest representable values are equally near, the one with its least significant bit zero is chosen. This is the IEEE 754 standard's default rounding mode known as **round to nearest**."

Comment: Accepted this answer since most platforms will follow IEEE 754. Still, do you happen to know if ActionScript 3 / Flash does so as well? I heard rumours that it can actually go wrong there.

Comment: It's the same for ActionScript. [Specs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f88.html) says it should use the IEEE format (and round-to-nearest is the default rounding mode.)

Answer (score -2):

Just round it, may be like this :

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d));
bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: `BigDecimal`? That's a pretty costly "fix" (if it is in fact needed) for a simple statement that may be executed too often for that.

Comment: This is not just costly, it's also a problem for the statistical characteristics of the random distribution.

Comment: no, i mean it just example, you can use other object type smaller than bigdecimal