# Random number generation

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expand a random range from 1-5 to 1-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7)

Hi,
  This question is taken from 
http://blog.seattleinterviewcoach.com/2009/02/140-google-interview-questions.html

> Given a function which produces a
>   random integer in the range 1 to 5,
>   write a function which produces a
>   random integer in the range 1 to 7.

I am not getting a way to generate all random numbers 1 to 7 with almost equal probability by using 1 to 5 random generator.

Could anyone pls solve it ?

Comment: Does the distribution have to be uniform? Do you get a uniform distribution from the provided function? Could you just ignore the provided function? :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the function you're given provides uniformly distributed-numbers and it is a strict requirement that the function you need to write also returns uniformly-distributed numbers.

The following pseudo-code illustrates the standard technique (called [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)):

```
do {
  rand25 = (rand5() - 1) * 5 + rand5; // 1-25
} while (rand25 > 21);
return (rand25 - 1) / 3 + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

What about func() + func() % 3 ?

Comment: just noticed, probability must be the same. This solution changes distribution.

Comment: This is a bad idea as it destroys the distribution properties of `func()`. In `func() % 3` getting a `1` or `2` is twice as likely to get a `0`, assuming `func()` has an equal distribution.