# How do you generate a random number in between 1 and 7 by using a function which generates 1 to 5

Tags: algorithm, math, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expand a random range from 1-5 to 1-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7)

I understood the solution using rejection sampling i.e

```
public static int rand7() {
    while (true) {
       int num = 5 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1);
       if (num < 21) return (num % 7 + 1);
    }
}
```

but I am thinking of another solution, i.e rand5() is called 7 times and result is divided by 5, but I am not sure whether this is correct.  Please let me know if is or isn't.

```
public static int rand7() {    
    int num = rand5()+rand5()+rand5()+rand5()+rand5()+rand5()+rand5();
    return num/5;
}
```

**EDIT:** It looks like the probability of generating 1 is (1/5)^7 but to generate 2 it is 7*(1/5)^7.  It is uneven so it is not going to work.

Comment: Seems to me like that should work, as should calling `rand5()` any number of times greater than or equal to 7 (accumulating the results in `sum`), and then taking `(sum % 7) + 1` as the result.

Comment: @aroth, that won't work. Assume you do it twice. You get a random value in the range (1, 10). Then 1, 2 and 3 will have higher probabilities than 4, 5, 6, 7.

Comment: @aioobe - You mean it won't produce an equal statistical likelihood for each number in the range.  Granted.  But the question is not stipulating that `rand7()` has to produce a statistically uniform distribution.  As I read it, any solution that *may* produce all values from 1-7 is valid, even if it produces `3` 99% of the time and one of `1,2,4,5,6,7` only 1% of the time.  Obviously that wouldn't be a very good random number generator, but it seems like it would satisfy the constraints of the question.

Comment: So [`return 4`](http://xkcd.com/221/) would be fine? That's a random number between 1 and 7, right? (If you're joking, please say so :-)

Comment: @Paul R: Not an exact duplicate. This question is about the veracity of a solution not provided in the question you have cited.

Comment: If you don't specify the distribution you want to get, then a function that always returns 3 is a legitimate answer.

Comment: @aioobe - No, that wouldn't quite work, since it can only ever result in 4.  And more like nitpicking over the semantics of the question than joking.  If we assume that "random" should mean "possessing a statistically uniform distribution" then of course you are correct.  Though from the information provided in the question, for all we know `rand5()` is implemented as `return 4`.

Comment: @aroth When the distribution is not specified it is usually implied that it is uniform. `return 4` is just an extreme case of a nonuniform distribution.

Comment: Every number between 1 and 5 is **already** a number between 1 and 7. *​trollface.jpg*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that other solution will generate a random number in the range 1..7, it will do so with a non-uniform probability distribution, i.e. the number 3 will be a lot more likely than the number 1.

In contrast, the rejection sampling approach will return all numbers in the range 1..7 with equal probability.

Comment: note that the second solution leads to normal distribution (gaussian curve). The first solution is OK.

Answer (score 3):

It will not be a uniform distribution (looks normal). And as Paul says, the proof follows from the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

[image]

Comment: For proof see Central Limit Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: @Hareendra: No problem. Also, if you think an answer is good, please upvote it. I have also noticed that you haven't *accepted* any answers. If you a specific answer answers your question best, please click on the tick-mark next to it. For more information, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct (at least not if the requirement is a uniform distribution, which is provided through rejection sampling).

If you had added two more `+ rand5()` terms, you would compute an approximation of the *average* a `rand5` function. As it stands now, you're basically compute an approximation of 7/5 × *the average* of the `rand5` function. (Which should be about 4.2.)

If you wanted a number between 1 and say 25, you could do

```
int[][] lut = { {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
                {  6,  7,  8,  9, 10},
                ...,
                { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 } }

return lut[rand5()][rand()]
```

This can not be done for 7 though, since 5 and 7 are co-prime. Rejection sampling is the best way to solve this.

Comment: No, it's not the average.  To get the average he would have to call `rand5()` 7 times, and then divide by 7.  He's calling 7 times and dividing by 5.  And as far as I can tell, the question doesn't make any stipulations about how the results of `rand7()` need to be distributed.  I think any solution that may possibly generate any value between 1 and 7 (inclusive) would be considered valid.

Comment: You get an approximately normal distribution this way rather than a rectangular distribution - see Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @aroth, updated the answer regarding the average. About the "distribution" I think we can safely assume that it's an even distribution the OP is after.

Comment: @ aroth, sorry for not including the details , i wanted a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to create an uniform rand7() function on base of uniform rand5() function. However it is possible to be as close as needed.

For example, if you are able to call rand5() 10 times in rand7(), you can get quite well quasi-uniform rand7(). If you are able to call it 100, then rand7() can be almost perfect, but never exactly uniform. This can be mathematically proven.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use rand5() on the bits of an octet, by assigning 0 to derived values 1 or 2, generating again on a 3, or assigning 1 for values 4 or 5.  If the final result is zero, then redo.  Here's some code:

```
public static int rand7() {
    int returnValue = 0;
    while (returnValue == 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            returnValue = (returnValue << 1) + rand5_output_2();
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}

private static int rand5_output_2() {
    while (true) {
        int flip = rand5();

        if (flip < 3) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (flip > 3) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He is not overcomplicating it. Your solution will not work as the function rand5() is apparently returning integer numbers. This way you get only numbers 1 2 4 5 7.

Comment: @Tomas, OK, wish he'd specified that.  Here's the best solution I found for integers.