# Find a random number generator using a given random number generating function

Tags: algorithm, random, number-theory

This is an interview question:

Given a function which generates a random number in [1,5],we need to use this function to generate a random number in the range [1,9].
I thought about it a lot but am not able to write an equation where ramdomness is satisfied.
People please answer.This might be helpful maybe in some future interviews.

Comment: do you want to have uniform probability distribution too ?

Comment: thats what randomness means i guess.

Comment: Given how the question is asked, I'm fairly sure that it has to yield a uniform distribution. Otherwise it makes no sense to ask that question.

Comment: Does the generated function generate integers or real numbers?

Comment: You can have a random number generator that doesn't have a uniform probability distribution. The trivial example is rolling two six sided dice. It's certainly random, but you're much less likely to roll a 12 than you are a 7.

Comment: This question has been answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-15-to-17

Comment: @doctore - this is quite famous question. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-15-to-17

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adapted from "[Expand a random range from 1–5 to 1–7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-15-to-17?rq=1)"

It assumes rand5() is a function that returns a statistically random integer in the range 1 through 5 inclusive.

```
int rand9()
{
    int vals[5][5] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 },
        { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    int result = 0;
    while (result == 0)
    {
        int i = rand5();
        int j = rand5();
        result= vals[i-1][j-1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

How does it work? Think of it like this: imagine printing out this double-dimension array on paper, tacking it up to a dart board and randomly throwing darts at it. If you hit a non-zero value, it's a statistically random value between 1 and 9, since there are an equal number of non-zero values to choose from. If you hit a zero, just keep throwing the dart until you hit a non-zero. That's what this code is doing: the i and j indexes randomly select a location on the dart board, and if we don't get a good result, we keep throwing darts.

this can run forever in the worst case, but statistically the worst case never happens. :)

Comment: Answer is Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-15-to-17?lq=1.

Comment: Just curious, if we have a function which generates a random number in [1,5], does it mean we can only create another function that generates a random number in the range [1,25] at most? how about [1,26], is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
int rand9()
{
    int t1,t2,res = 10;
    do {
        t1 = rand5();
        do {
            t2 = rand5();
        }while(t2==5);
        res = t1 + 5* (t2%2);
    }while(res==10);
    return res;
}
```

now 1 to 9 has the probability of 1/9.

make some explanation:

t1 has probability of 1/5 to be 1 to 5.

t2,too.but when t2==5,discarded.so t2 has probability of 1/4 to be 1 to 4.that' to say, probability of 1/2 to be odd or even,which makes t2%2 has probability of 1/2 to be 0 to 1.

thus, t1 + 5*(t2%2) has probability of 5/10 to be 1 to 5, and 5/10 to be 6 to 10.
but 10 is discarded again,so the rest 9 numbers' probability is 1/9.

Comment: This isn't random either, numbers 2 and 4 occurs twice as many times as the rest, and 9 none at all.

Comment: I've change res = t1*(1+  t2%2) to res = t1+ 5* t2%2, now it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The code as it stands now produces numbers from 1 to 6 (and not 7-9), and 2-5 occurs twice as often as 1 and 6. I have a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program here you can try that shows you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7m9sb4jqto9f15/SO17190340.linq

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are right, I find that I left out brackets outside the t2%2,which is not my original idea.When I add them up and test the function in my gcc by using  (1+rand()%5) as rand5(), it works rightly. I fix my code and add up some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). That is, reject results that don't fit your target distribution. In your case you could use the lower three bits of two successive calls to your `rand15` function (− 1 if necessary), concatenate them and reject those results that are outside your target interval and retry until you find a number that's inside.