# Creating a function to generate a random number

Tags: python

*Note: I cannot use any of the built in functions to solve this.*

This is the question:

Given a function that returns a random integer number between 1 and 5, create a function that creates a random integer between 1 and 7.

Comment: yeah its a question i got in interview!

Comment: what did you try and where did you get stuck? (sounds like a homework thread if you cant use builtin stuff?)

Comment: pfft. this is homework and you clearly haven't made the slightest effort.

Comment: alright... im removing it..

Comment: @SpliFF This is a somewhat famous google interview question. That already has an answer on this site

Comment: Perfect solution is here http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: I think the question itself is a joke / trick question. A function that returns a random integer number between 1 and 5 ALREADY meets the second criteria because every number in the range 1 - 5 is also between 1 and 7

Comment: This is an interesting question (although it should show an attempt - I can think of a number of invalid approaches), *but the title is absolutely horrid*.

Comment: @Spliff it most likely have to have a quite even distribution between the numbers when it has been run a lot of times, else it really makes no sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-15-to-17 eh...answered a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been answered in [Adam Rosenfield's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137809/2948265) a while ago you may try to use an algoritm similar to this one below:

```
int i;
do
{
  i = 5 * (rand5() - 1) + rand5();  // i is now uniformly random between 1 and 25
} while(i > 21);
// i is now uniformly random between 1 and 21
return i % 7 + 1;  // result is now uniformly random between 1 and 7
```

EDIT: Translation to python:

```
def rand7():
i = 0;

while True:
    i = 5 * (rand5() -1) + rand5()
    if i > 21:
        break
return i % 7 + 1
```

Comment: But all right I've added a python version. Please check it as I'm not experienced in this language.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the following [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137833/2864740). See the linked answer and the other responses as well.

---

Well, here is an approach I am thinking of. It could be wrong. I am going with the assumption that the result should be randomly distributed within the larger range.

Generate 7 random numbers using the given random functions (that generates numbers [1,5]) and calculate their sum.

This will result in a value between 7 (1 * 7) and 35 (5 * 7).

Because this value is evenly divisible by the target range and randomly distributed, then it seems like it would be valid to collapse the intermediate range [7,35] back to [1,7] without losing uniformity.

Or maybe that's not quite it - but it seems like exploiting a common multiple between the numbers is key.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
def winningFunc():
   return originalFuncReturning1to5() + random.randint(0,2)
```

Comment: reason for negative vote?

Comment: Because he can't use built-in functions.

Comment: `Note: I cannot use any of the built in functions to solve this.`

Comment: Even if he would be able to use built-in functions this is not very good as a random functions as it's not uniform.