# Create a Random Number Generator method from A given Random number generator method with different range

Tags: algorithm, random

I want to make a Random number generator using a given random number generator method.

> Given a function randK() that return a random number from 1 to
>   k, create a function randN() that return a random number from 1 to n with
>   equal probability.

where `k` can be be both less than or more than `n` `(k<n or k>n)`.

I understand if `(k > n)` we can keep calling randK() till it return `(value <= n)`.

1. but will the `equal probability`  property be maintained.?
2. Also what about the case when `(k<n)` ?

`

Comment: It's not clear in the question where the `k` and `n` variables come from. I'm guessing that `k` is a constant (built into the existing `f` function) and `n` is an argument to the `fn` function. Is that correct?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7 . Also when k < n , assuming rand is function which generates number from 1 to n you can do round(rand/n*k) for better distribution.

Comment: @Blckknght yes that absolutely correct

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande that seems to be a specific case. It would be great if we can come up with a equation something like randN() = a*randK() + C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, all numbers between `1` to `k` will have the same probability to appear, and that probability will be `1 / k` (not `1 / n`), so they all are equally probable (also, if `k - n` is high, then the number of calls to *f()* inside *fn()* may increase).

---

2) Create a *x-tuple* of values `(f(), f(), ..., f())`, where *x* is the smaller integer that satisfies the following in-equation: **k<sup>x</sup> >= n**

We only care about *x* such that *k<sup>x</sup> > n*, which will turn the  problem back to case 1 (where `k > n`). If the generated x-tuple is outside the first n tuples, start again.

**Example:** Given *f()* that returns a number in `[1, 5]` (equally probable), you want to create *fn()* that returns a number in `[1, 10]` (also equally probable).

The first integer *x* that satisfies *5<sup>x</sup> >= 10* is *x = 2*, (25 >= 10).

Then your *x-tuple* is of the form `(f(), f())` (just a tuple), call the function *f()* twice and apply case 1:

```
(1,1) = 1, (1,2) = 2, (1,3) = 3, 
(1,4) = 4, (1,5) = 5, (2,1) = 6, 
(2,2) = 7, (2,3) = 8, (2,4) = 9 and (2,5) = 10
```

If you get one of the other 15 tuples [(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5)] repeat the algorithm again until you get one the first 10 tuples.

The 10 tuples have the same probability of 1/25 to appear.

Answer (score 1):

This is for case when k > n. The logic is from this link - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-integer-from-1-to-7-with-equal-probability/ . Consider randn generates number from 1 to n and randk generates number from 1 to k.

```
int i = randn*n + randn - n;
int j = n*n/k;
while ( i < j*k + 1){
   i = randn*n + randn - n; 
}
return i%k + 1;
```

This should generate numbers from 1 to k with equal probability.