# What is the time complexity of the following code

Tags: time-complexity

```
int rand7()
{
    int vals[5][5] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6, 7, 1 },
        { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    int result = 0;
    while (result == 0)
    {
        int i = rand5();
        int j = rand5();
        result = vals[i-1][j-1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

This solution solves the problem listed in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7).

Comment: `O(ff-topic)`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *worst-case running time* will be infinite if you keep on getting `i`, `j` such that `vals[i-1][j-1] == 0`, so the `while` loop will never terminate. This situation almost surely does not happen though.

Let `T` denotes the *expected running time* of `rand7()`, we have the following observation:

- if `i == 1, 2, 3, 4`, then no matter what `j` is, we will have `vals[i-1][j-1] != 0`, so the `while` loop will iterate only once in this case; - **This event occurs with probability 4/5**
- if `i == 5` and `j == 1`, then `vals[i-1][j-1] != 0` and the `while` loop will iterate only once; - **This event occurs with probability 1/25**
- in the remaining cases we have `vals[i-1][j-1] == 0`, so we need to start over with new random values `(i, j)`. - **This occurs happens with probability 4/25**

From the observation above, we have the following relationship:

```
T = 4/5 * 1 + 1/25 * 1 + 4/25 * (1 + T)
```

Therefore the expected running time is `T = 25/21 = O(1)`.