# How to generate a random number <= 7 from two random numbers <= 5?

Tags: algorithm, random

Here is the reference implementation and I do not understand why choose 21 here? Thanks.

```java
public static int rand7() {
    while (true) {
        int num = 5 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1);
        if (num < 21) return (num % 7 + 1);
    }
}
```

BTW, I read that question before asking, my specific question is why using 21 here. In that thread, it is not answered. If I missed anything, please feel free to correct. Thanks. :)
thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: This isn't [tag:python], it's [tag:java]. Anyway this is a duplicate of [Expand a random range from 1–5 to 1–7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7)

Comment: @smci, I read that question before asking, my specific question is why using 21 here. In that thread, it is not answered. If I missed anything, please feel free to correct. Thanks. :)

Comment: @smci, I mean why not using 14 or 7 here. This is my question. And thanks for correcting, it is not Python. I am using Python. :)

Comment: I don't know, but in that other question, they are generating a number <= 21. So it's not even a 7-bit number. Also, the code here is wrong `if (num < 21) ...` should be `>= 21`. It would help if you state the source of this question.

Comment: @smci, thanks and my question is why use 21 other than 14 or 7? 14 and 7 are all times of 7. Any insights are appreciated. :)

Comment: this isn't generate a random number < 21. it'll return a number from 1-7

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, thanks for the inputs and my confusion is how do get this formula?  5 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1), why not using other formulas? :)

Comment: @LinMa because `rand(5)-1` produces a digit in base 5, so they multiply it by 5 to make it the 5s' unit

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, thanks and wondering why should we multiple by 5, could we multiple by other numbers, saying 3 or 4? For example, 3 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1), or 4 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because 21 is a multiple of 7.

The term `5 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1)` produces a number in the range `[0, 24]` (uniform distribution). This is then used to create a random number in `[0, 6]` by `% 7`. However, this does not produce a uniform distribution if you use the entire range. The remainders 0, 1, 2, 3 occur once more than the remainders 4, 5, 6. Therefore, the according numbers that produce one of these remainders are cut off and only the range `[0, 20]` (`< 21`) is used. You could equivalently cut off the first 4 numbers (`> 3`) to produce a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks Nico, and my question is why use 21 other than 14 or 7? 14 and 7 are all times of 7. Any insights are appreciated. :)

Comment: Because you want to discard as few numbers as possible in order to return a valid number as soon as possible. 21 is the greatest multiple of 7 which is smaller or equal to 25 (=5^2).

Comment: Thanks Nico, smart answer. Then the question is, why we use 5 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1), which results in distribution from [0,24], why not use other ranges? I think as long as the range is larger than 7 and uniformly distributed, it is fine? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You could use any range. But [0, 24] is probably the most straight-forward (it is a two-digit number in base 5).

Comment: Thanks Nico, why we should something base 5? More detailed insights are appreciated. :)

Comment: Because then we can just use the generated numbers as digits of another number. You can read more about positional notation on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation).

Comment: Thanks Nico, thanks and wondering why should we multiple by 5, could we multiple by other numbers, saying 3 or 4? For example, 3 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1), or 4 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1)

Comment: But then the digits' ranges overlap and you end up with a non-uniform distribution again. E.g. for `3 * (rand5() - 1) + (rand5() - 1)`, the number `4` can be expressed both as `3 * 0 + 4` and as `3 * 1 + 1`.

Comment: Thanks Nico, smart and smart. Mark as answered. :)