# Generating a random number from 0 to 9 based on a series of coin flips

Tags: math, random

What method can I use to **minimize** the amount of coin flips needed to generate a uniformly distributed number from 0 to 9?

I've done some research, but I haven't been able to figure out how to adapt it to this specific problem:

- [Expand a random range from 1–5 to 1–7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7/)
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-a-fair-6-sided-die-to-generate-a-random-number-from-1-to-20-with-each-outcome-occurring-with-the-same-probability
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/570/generating-uniformly-distributed-random-numbers-using-a-coin

Comment: Minimize on average or minimize the upper bound?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The average number of flips is what I was thinking of.

Comment: Then the first most efficient variant is to use 10 flips to generate a binary number <1024, reject results >999 and use the 3 digits as 3 random numbers in that range. It should be hard and unpractical to improve on that.

Answer (score 2):

You would need atleast 10 possible combinations while flipping the coin. We would have 16 permutations if the coins are flipped 4 times. So, the minimum number of flips required would be 4.

By referring to the algorithms mentioned in your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7/), we can implement the problem as follows.

The variable `randNum` returns a uniformly distributed random number between 0-9.

The function `rand2` simulates the coin flipping exercise by assigning 0 and 1 value to T and H or vice versa.

```
int[][][][] fourDimArr = { { { {1, 2},{3, 4} }, {{5, 6} ,{7, 8} } }, { { {9,10},{0,0} }, { {0,0},{0,0} } } };
int result = 0;
    while (result == 0)
    {
        int i = rand2();
        int j = rand2();
        int k = rand2();
        int l = rand2();
        result = fourDimArr[i][j][k][l];
    }
int randNum = result-1;
```

A simpler and more intuitive implementation is suggested by [James K Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/james-k-polk) in the comments below. It involves using the outcomes of the coin flips as     bits of a four bit number.

By rejecting values >= 10 , we would generate a uniformly distributed random number between 0-9. For implementation, refer the code snippet below.

```
int result = 11;
        while(result>=10){
            result = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                result = (result<<1)|rand2();
            }
        }
randNum = result;
```

An example implementation of rand2 is as follows:

```
private static int rand2() {
    if(Math.random()>0.5)return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: The minimum number of flips required is 4. The number of flips required in the worst case is still infinite, but this condition never arises.*

Comment: This is a very complex variation of simply taking each of the four flips as one of the bits in a four bit number; accept the result if it is < 10, otherwise reject the result and redo the flips.