# Compute rand5 given rand7

Tags: algorithm, random

It's a common interview question to generate a larger range of random numbers using a random number generator for a smaller range. For example, given a function `rand5` that randomly generates numbers from 0 to 5, create `rand7`. There is a SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137783/839733) for that.

How do we do the opposite, create `rand5` given `rand7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is quite simple, in pseudo-code:

```
do {
    r = rand7
} while r>5
return r;
```

Comment: Of course, but does it generate a uniform distribution?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar it depends on rand7, if it is uniform - this function will be also uniform