# Given a random int generator [0-5], generate [0-7]

Tags: algorithm

So this was an interview question.

You are provided with a function `rand5()` which generates a random integer in the range [0-5] i.e. {0,1,2,3,4,5}

a) Can you use that function to generate a random integer in the range [0-7]?

b) Can you use that function to generate a random integer in the range [0-7] with each number having equal probability?

You may use the function multiple times.

One of the solution for part a, `((rand5() +rand5())*7)//10` where `// represents integer division` would give you the range [0-7] however the probabilities are not equal.

Would love to see your answers and thought process on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand a random range from 1–5 to 1–7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7)

Comment: I believe SO questions are marked as duplicates provided the duplicate has an *accepted* answer.

Comment: @גלעדברקן What is the basis for your belief?

Comment: @erickson I researched a little and could not find policies or meta posts that support my claim. It's possible I saw a comment to that effect somewhere. Also, I always assumed the duplicate-question wording after it's closed to the effect of "this question already has an answer..." equated "having an answer" with having an accepted answer. I guess it's more nuanced, though.

Answer (score 5):

```
    $one  = rand5();
    $two  = rand5();
    $four = rand5();

    return (($four < 3)? 4 : 0)  +  (($two < 3)? 2 : 0)  +  ($one < 3)? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: can you modify this approach to work with, say 9 instead of 7?

Comment: Nice one, although shouldn't it be `>= 3`? (so 0, 1, 2 are 0 and 3, 4, 5 are 1). Maybe worth noting this approach works whenever the source random function produces an even number of values and the desired range is from zero to a power of two minus one.

Comment: Once agian, the probability of having lower numbers is higher than lower numbers in this example. EDIT: I guess only with 2,5 you got even chances.

Comment: Probability of getting 7 is 1/27, not 1/8

Comment: @MBo Can you explain? Probability of getting three heads in a row is 2^(-3) = 1/8.

Comment: @erickson Yes, but we have here not 0/1 coin, but rand5() giving result 0..5, and probality of (4 or 5) is 1/3. P.S. I should write "Probability of getting 7 using this approach"

Comment: @MBo Ah, right. My comment was based on the assumption that he'd fix that bug as mentioned above.

Comment: People are upvoting this, but as written it does not give a uniform distribution.  Also, this approach will not work if the targeted number of outcomes isn't a power of 2 - in that case you need a rejection scheme.

Comment: @pjs yeah, but it's a trivial fix and it does answer the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [Rejection Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).
Consider the rolls arranged in a 2D grid like below

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now if you roll the die twice you can generate any position in the 2D grid (first row for row position, second for column position). There are `36` positions in total. Since we want to generate numbers in `[0, 7]` range we need output space to be a multiple of `8`. If we consider first `32` positions (in a row major order) we can split them into group of `4` indices. For example

```
[0, 1, 2, 3] in first row => 0
[4, 5, 0, 1] in first and second row => 1
[2, 3, 4, 5] in second row => 2
...
[4, 5, 0, 1] in fifth and sixth row => 7
```

If we roll last `4` positions, we will just roll again.

```
int rand7() {
    while(true) {
        int row = rand(5);
        int col = rand(5);
        int pos = row * 6 + col;
        if(pos < 32) {
            return pos/4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842183/2034787) with over 550 votes for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

- **rand5()** yields random number between *0-5* with equal probability. Also three numbers (*0, 2, 4*) returned by **rand5()** are even and other three(*1, 3, 5*) are odd. Thus it yields even and odd numbers with equal probability.
- if **rand7()** returns all numbers with equal probability, then the probability of *6* in **rand7()** should be **1/8**. Also probability of **rand5()** returning even number *thrice* is **1/8**.

Thus **rand7()** can be:

```js
// returns random number between 0-5 with equal probability
function rand5() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
}

// returns random number between 0-7 with equal probability
function rand7() {
  if(rand5() % 2 == 0 && rand5() % 2 == 0) { 
    return 6 + rand5() % 2;
  } else {
    return rand5();
  }
}

console.log(rand7());
```

Answer (score 0):

A die has an equal chance to roll any side. If the desired range is smaller than the range of the die, simply re-roll when it's out of bounds.

The problem comes when the desired range is larger than the range of one die. The sum of multiple dice rolls is not-quite-normally distributed, so that adding the value of multiple rolls won't work.

Instead, think about using successive rolls to progressively "zoom in" on a value within a subrange. If we roll a 6-sided die twice, the first roll would select a 6-unit subrange—for example, 12–17, inclusive. The second roll would select a single value from that subrange, like 14.

Again, as with a single die, if the range is larger than desired, simply reject values that are out of bounds, and roll again.