# Salts and Passwords - prefix or postfix

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, salt

This is a question about salting phrases that need to be hashed.

I was wondering if it more secure to prefix the salt to a phrase or postfix it?
salt + phrase or
phrase + salt

My question comes from this [comment](http://www.skrenta.com/2007/08/md5_tutorial.html#comment-10072) on this post on [MD5s](http://www.skrenta.com/2007/08/md5_tutorial.html). I am not sure I understand the reasoning behind the author's comment.

Comment: The real question is why are you using MD5?

Comment: asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674904/salting-your-password-best-practices

Comment: I still havent gotten a reasonable explanation regarding the comment  by Dru Nelson on skrenta's blog post about MD5. But the consensus seems to be (only by majority), that the placement of the salt makes no difference. I just dont want to be overlooking something (that is if Dru Nelson is indeed on to something in his comment)

Comment: Dru Nelson's comment on Skrenta's blog post is reproduced here for your reading convenience:

however i will add.. your handwaving example of using

hash = md5(s . 'xyzzy')

to overcome a malicious party who wants to cause collisions is not going to work. appending the same thing to two messages that hash the same will yield two new messages that hash the same. in fact, this is what makes it so easy to create arbitrary messages which hash to the same thing (it does not require a "sophisticated attacker" at all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether the salt is appended to the front or the back makes no difference.

The following factors will affect security though

1. Is your salt private (if so how private is it?). The more private the better. This means that if you can avoid storing your salt in your db you can make your system safe against brute force attacks even if your db is compromised.
2. Is your salt random per value salted? This helps defend against rainbow table attacks if say your db is compromised and your salt is stored in the db. Note: if passwords being stored are long enough they can be immune to brute force attacks.
3. Is your salt long enough? The longer your salt the more secure you are.

Comment: It wasn't me (I upvoted) but I'd guess because of your first bullet. A private salt doesn't really add security. Even if a cracker gains access to the hash and salt, as long as the salt is long enough and random per password, a rainbow table is computationally prohibitive.

Comment: Sure, but brute forcing short password is still very much possible if the salt is public

Comment: @SamSaffron : This is a necro-reply, but prefixing the salt is a bad idea because it makes it easier to brute-force the password. If you hash the salt/password bytes of `sssspppp`, the attacker can compute a hash-state for the known `ssss` portion and then use it as a "base camp" for repeatedly attacking the unknown `pppp` portion.

Comment: **If a salt is more private than the hash, it isn't a salt at all.** Something that's private is a key (so perhaps you're using a keyed hash function), not a salt.

Answer (score 2):

When someone has a question about the use of salts I fear it is because they are busy (re)inventing things they really shouldn't be in the first place.  Based on the question my recommendation is to use an HMAC.

Comment: if you use HMAC you still need a private key which has to be stored somewhere ... same factors that affect the salt based security affect the choice of key for your hmac algorithm

Comment: The question was about the location of salts - NOT key management. HMAC use solves the location issue.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter when you digest the salt: prefix, postfix, infix all produce different hashes, but achieve the same purpose of defeating rainbow tables or other pre-hashed dictionary attacks.

I think that the comment has to do specifically with a vulnerability in MD5, not hashing in general. I don't understand the details, but it [has to do with finding two prefixes that produce the same hash.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5#Vulnerability)

Comment: Thats not the way collision attacks work. you need to know the full message being hashed to produce collisions. you can not produce collisions from a partial message

Comment: You find two different messages that produce a hash collision. Then you append the same suffix to each of these prefixes and you get another collision. I think the cited comment was trying to explain a password crack that used this vulnerability, but I don't understand exactly how he thought it works.

Comment: Really? The output of MD5 is simply its last intermediate hash value. If you have two different prefixes that collide it means the intermediate hash value is the same—and that value is the entire state of the hash. If two MD5 hashes in an identical state digest the same data, what would you expect the results to be? See http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/

Comment: comment stricken, true, if you prefix collides and you append the same suffix it will result in a collision as well. I have no idea how this could be exploited though in a password storage scenario

Answer (score 1):

unlike what others said, it does matter! and as @einstein if you care use `HMAC`.

why prefix is bad, because one can calculate the intermediate state of the checksum up to the given fixed salt prefix. then start calculating the rest in parallel. In summary `phrase+salt` is more secure than `salt+phrase`, but `HMAC(salt, phrase)` is even better.

[related reading](https://latacora.singles/2018/08/03/the-default-openssh.html)

Answer (score -2):

Technically it doesn't matter, so long as the salt is unique and not easily guessable. Just don't make the mistake of storing the salt, like I did.

The purpose of "salting" a string is to scramble it in a way a bit more personal and unique than an MD5 hash will do. There's no right or wrong way to do it, just so long as you're the only one that knows how it works. It will achieve the result either way, which is to make the MD5 hashes generated *not* correspond with a rainbow table for easy cracking of passwords.

Comment: Well, technically doing it a particular way can prevent against that mindset if a cracker assumes a common way. In other words, prefix and postfix are more/less vulnerable against certain threats, if my research is valid. So the downvote may be appropriate if you're security paranoid, I don't pretend to be the know-all expert on such things. ^_^

Comment: -1 Salt is stored openly with the encrypted password to defend against amortizing attacks over many encrypted passwords. It shouldn't be confused with a private key.

Comment: Wha? I was always under the impression that a salt was prefixed/postfixed to a password *before* hashing. Clearly I was mistaken then, I get to go do more research. Yay!

Comment: @SamSaffron, the reason to downvote it is that it's wrong. "Salt" is a technical term with a specific meaning, and having the same level of security as the hash itself is part of that meaning. If something is private, it's not salt, it's a key (and maybe you're using a HMAC-keyed hash instead of a salted hash).