# What comes first, the salt or the hash?

Tags: hash, salt

Okay, I know this is probably dead simple, but I can't seem to find a straight answer anywhere.  Let's say I have the following:

```
Password: "mypassword"
Salt: 1234567
```

Is the idea of salting to do something like `hash(password + salt)` or `hash(password) + salt`?  My guess is that only the former makes any sense at all, but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've got it, it's the former.

If you just concatenated the salt and the hash, then an attacker can simply remove the "salt" and use a rainbow table. By hashing the plaintext + salt, the salt cannot be factored out.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, it's `salt + hash(salt+password)` (Salt is part of the hash computation - but you must also keep it in the clear)

Comment: why do you need the first salt? Wouldn't it be pointless as a hacker would just ignore it?

Comment: You need to store it (in the clear) because without it you won't be able to check the password.

Answer (score 8):

hash(password + salt). If you concatenate the salt after the hashing, the concatenation is easily reversible and doesn't add any difficulty in reversing the hash on the password (with rainbow tables).

That said, some systems do both, e.g. Django stores salt$hash(salt+password) in database. This is simply so that every piece of data needed to check the password against the hash is available in one place.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding these links into this question for completeness - this topic of salty hashing requires a broad understanding of the topics feeding into it to avoid costly mistakes.

A key point not quite expressed in the answers here is the necessity of using a unique salt for *each* password. For details on why, read the linked items.

Why make each salt unique : [Salting Your Password: Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674904/salting-your-password-best-practices/674931#674931)

Broad overview on the topic : [Salt Generation and open source software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190)

Answer (score 0):

The salt should be part of the hash calculation