# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, email) VALUES ('testu', 'testp', 'teste')
```

I am getting this error with the following VB code (ASP):

```
    username = Request.Form("username")
    password = Request.Form("password")
    email = Request.Form("email")

    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString())
    Dim comm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('" & username & "', '" & password & "', '" & email & "')", conn)

    conn.Open()
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

What is wrong with this statement? I know the connection string is correct because I have used it throughout the rest of my application.

Comment: Ah, SQL injection.

Comment: **Never** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Always use parameters for query !!

Comment: FYI... your code is open to sql inject... and what is the exact error message your get?

Comment: It is for a very small school project, I am not worried about SQL injection.

Comment: Try this: `Dim query as String = "INSERT INTO users (...` copying your query. Then edit your question posting `query` value. As someone said, there could be some _strange_ char in params...

Comment: I did. That is the second line of my question.

Comment: No, it's not: your query seems like `"INSERT INTO users` while your second line uses table name within backticks!

Comment: I changed the backticks to see if that made a difference while typing the question. What I posted is what I get when I output the query.

Comment: And just to be clear: you **must** always be worried about SQL injection and you should never store passwords in plain text. It's a really bad practice!

Comment: Marco, I am well aware of those problems which I have said several times. Thanks though, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree! Always use Parameter (prepared) query and hash salt your password. Read SO thread -  [Salting Your Password: Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674904/salting-your-password-best-practices) .

```
 Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString())
 Dim comm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO users (username, [password], email) VALUES (@username,@password,@email)",conn)
 comm.Parameters.Add("@username",OleDbType.Varchar,30).Value=username
 ....
```

Comment: Like I said it is for a very small school project. I am aware of prepared queries and salting. The problem here is the query I mentioned not working, and I do not believe using parameters will solve that (but I could be wrong).

Comment: @LoganSerman - Password is reserved word of access database engine so you have to escape. See the edited post. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx

Comment: Thank you, AVD. That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't EVER pass parameters to SQL commands with concatenation! This is an open way for SQL injection attack.

You should use placeholders for parameters and add actual values using comm.AddParameter().

As for your error - I'd expect some of your parameter values contains a single quote (').