# How to compare login credentials against a database using JDBC (PostgreSQL)

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, messenger

So I am attempting to make a simple chat messenger in Eclipse. At the moment I am stumped on how to compare the users login details against those stored in a database table. I have an 'askName()' method that takes a username and password, and this needs to use my 'authenticate' method to check details stored in a Login table in the database.

I have been searching here and all over online, and have found a lot of code which has been useful for getting ideas. However I have been banging my head against this for a while and am still very new to programming, any help would be greatly appreciated!

So at the moment inside the Client class I have these login methods:

```
public void askName()
{
    // get the clients name
    boolean b = true;
    // loop in case they enter a null name - aint nobody got time for that
    while(b == true)
    {
        out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = null;
        try {
            name = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't read name");
        }           
        out.println("What is your password?");
        String password = null;
        try {
            password = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't read password");
        }           
        if(name != null && password != null)
        {
            if(Authenticate(name, password))
            {
                this.username = name;
                b = false;
                out.println("Welcome " + this.username);
            } else {
                out.println("Invalid username/password combination!");
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("Please enter a valid username and password. Your name must contain at least one letter");
        }   
    }
}

private boolean Authenticate(String name, String password) { // added by Alex 18/03/14
    // Method to check the entered username/password is valid against the database

    // No database class at this point

    //Database database = new Database(); 

    return database.Authenticate(name, password);

}
```

I have managed to implement the database in class 'MyJDBC' and just need to figure out how to use my 'authenticate' method to check the details. I am using PostgreSQL. This is the current query I have made for checking login credentials "SELECT password FROM userlogin WHERE username ='"+name+"'"

```
package jdbc;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MyJDBC {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Testing");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                    + "Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:postgresql://dbteach2.cs.bham.ac.uk:5432/user",
"username",
"password");
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT password FROM userlogin WHERE username ='"+name+"'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String Username = rs.getString("Username");
                String Password = rs.getString("Password");
                int sid = rs.getInt("sid");
                System.out.println("Username = " + Username);
                System.out.println("Password = " + Password);
                System.out.println("sid = " + sid);
                System.out.println();
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }}
```

I am not asking anyone to do my code, but some advice on what I could do/what I am doing wrong would be appreciated. If you would like to see the rest of my code to try it out please say so.

Comment: First of all password should always be hashed with a salt (eg using something like PBKDF2 or bcrypt), and not be stored in plaintext.

Comment: That is a good point, thanks. At the moment I just want to get the authentication working so am just using stored user details in the table. Once this is working I will work on improving the details such as sending and storing the password securely.

Comment: You should design and develop with security in mind from the start, not hack it in afterwards.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I am new to programming and this is my first actual project - I will bare this in mind!

Comment: Who else wants to create an account and join chatting with kimbleoffice? -Little Bobby Tables _(ok that was just a heads-up for that little sneaky SQL injection bug in OP's code :D)_

Answer (score 2):

**In practice you clearly should not use clear text passwords, you should hash and salt them**. Then apply the same hash and salt to the entered passwort and match them like I will descibe below. Pretty straight forward.

*As you asked to know the basic process, here it is:*
Retrieve the password for your `userlogin`, `userlogin` should be `unique` so there will only be one tuple in the `ResultSet`. If there's no row retrieved for that `username`, the user doesnt exist --> throw an `Exception`.

Next is to match your retrieved password with the one the user entered via `retrievedPw.equals(userEnteredPw)`. If it returns true, log the user in as his credentials are correct.

If it comes to salting I myself struggled with the word a bit ago, so you may want to read [This disucssion on salting best practices.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674904/salting-your-password-best-practices)

Comment: I'll +1 if you put the "salt and hash" first :-)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

- add  hashed password in the database for security reason
- use prepared statements to avoid  SQL injection attacks
- add proper closing of resources to avoid headache on production