# How to Hash Submitted passwords using JdbcRealm in Shiro?

Tags: shiro, jdbcrealm

I've created an application and been using Shiro for the authentication.
I've followed most of the guides and also some of the posted questions here regarding shiro and Jdbc Realm.

Here is my shiro.ini file:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl=/jsp/loginForm.jsp
authc.successUrl=/test/successUrl.jsp
authc.rememberMeParam = login-remember-me
logout.redirectUrl=/index.jsp

hashService = org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations = 500000
hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
hashService.generatePublicSalt = true

hashService.privateSalt = someBase64EncodedSaltValue

realm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
realm.permissionsLookupEnabled = false
realm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM userTable WHERE username = ?

ps = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
ps.hashService = $hashService
pm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
pm.passwordService = $ps

jof = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
jof.resourceName = java:comp/env/jdbc/theResourceName
jof.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
jof.resourceRef = true

realm.dataSource = $jof
realm.credentialsMatcher = $pm

securityManager.realms = $realm
```

and i'm using the following code in Java to save the password in the database:

```
DefaultHashService hashService = new DefaultHashService();
hashService.setHashIterations(500000);
hashService.setHashAlgorithmName(Sha256Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
hashService.setPrivateSalt(new SimpleByteSource(
    "someBase64EncodedSaltValue")); // Same salt as in shiro.ini, but NOT
                                      // base64-encoded.
hashService.setGeneratePublicSalt(true);

DefaultPasswordService pwService = new DefaultPasswordService();
pwService.setHashService(hashService);
this.password = pwService.encryptPassword(password);
```

Everything looks good and is saving as expected but the problem is when I am logging in. I've traced the execution to JdbcRealm.class and I've seen that the value compared is the "raw string password" and the encrypted password from the database.

Did I miss any step configuring?

Answer (score 0):

To use Salted its better to have seperate salt for every user. So store that salt in database. [SEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674904/salting-your-password-best-practices)

Now,
Extend `org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm` like:

```
package common.shiro;

import org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm;

public class JDBCSaltedRealm extends JdbcRealm  {

    public JDBCSaltedRealm() {
        setSaltStyle(SaltStyle.COLUMN);
    }
}
```

In shiro.ini:

```
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 500000
credentialsMatcher.hashSalted = true

realm = common.shiro.JDBCSaltedRealm

realm .permissionsLookupEnabled = true
realm .authenticationQuery  = SELECT password,salt  FROM userTable WHERE username = ?
realm .dataSource = $jof
realm .credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
securityManager.realm = $realm
```

Comment: I tried it and it still fails to match the password typed and the password stored in the database.