# Selecting two columns for SqlCommand class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to find out whether there is a way to select two columns in the same table  for a single SqlCommand which would be afterwards used for comparison between data in the two columns and data in two textBoxes:

Below are two strings what I use at the moment for SqlCommand class and would like to put them together:

```
String str1 = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [User Name] LIKE '{0}'", txtUserName.Text);
String str2 = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [Password] LIKE '{0}'", txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: You are wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please use bind parameters in any language you can. C# has them, use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `AND` in your sql query and sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection:

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] 
               WHERE [User Name] = @UserName
                 AND [Password]  = @Password";
using(var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but shouldn't it be `OR`? And why do you pass `%` as the parameter's values?

Comment: @stakx: i'm not sure, maybe. It's not that clear what OP is actually trying to achieve. According to the `%`: it was just a partly removed part of my answer. My first version contained the `LIKE` but it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to improve....

1. Do not use string concatenation/formatting to form SQL queries, you are prone to SQL injection. **Parametrize your queries**. Use `SqlParameter`
2. **Important!**. Do not use `LIKE` to compare against user name and password, you *probably* want exact match using `=`
3. You need to combine two conditions using `AND` operator.

So your code should look like:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
using (
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [UserName] = @userName AND [Password] = @password",
            connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
    connection.Open();
    //,... execute command
}
```

One last thing to add, **do not store password text in database**, instead store their hashes, see: [How to store passwords *correctly*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829838/how-to-store-passwords-correctly)

Comment: @fubo, I replied after during the same time, I don't think I can copy that much in one and half minute. By the way did you miss all the other details ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
String str1 = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [User Name] LIKE '{0}'", txtUserName.Text);
String str2 = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [Password] LIKE '{0}'", txtPassword.Text);
```

Do

```
String str1 = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [User Name] LIKE '{0}', SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [Password] LIKE '{1}", txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```