# Password salt & secret

Tags: python, performance, security, google-app-engine, passwords

So when building a webapp and storing passwords, both security and performance are important things to keep in mind. Having seen evidence that even salted SHA1 passwords can be easily cracked due to the increasing speed of GPUs, I was wondering what are the best practices of storing passwords.

I thought that in order to add more security to storing passwords, you could add a secret to the salt. So for instance, the python code for this could be:

```
import hashlib
import hmac

secret = 'XYZ'
h = hmac.new('salt' + secret, 'password')
```

- Is this a common thing to do?
- What are the drawbacks of this?
- What are the best practices in this field?

*P.S. I didn't post this in the security forum because I want a webapp developer's perspective.*

Comment: I don't see a big difference here, because the big deal for cracking a password is how hard to reverse a hashed value. So even your salt is now more secure, it may just help a little bit (e.g. by eliminating the use of certain rainbow tables). A random secret for session is usually obtained by generating random bits such as using urandom call.

Comment: Just a note: [Python *hmac*](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html)’s default hashing function is MD5. And the algorithm of HMAC is in simple terms just applying the hash function twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also have a look at passlib: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/passlib/

Comment: If this is for app engine, SHA512_crypt is recommended because it uses C-code which enables more rounds than bcrypt/scrypt/pbkdf which is python only. Store method name along with hash and you can switch and be backwards compatible if any of the others get C implementation on GAE.

Answer (score 4):

You're just making your salt a bit longer... Namely, your salt is now `saltXYZ` instead of just `salt`.

From my perspective, this isn't any different from just using a regular salt, so that makes your first two questions moot.

As far as best practices go, the most important one is "never roll your own crypto". Don't get fancy, use a well known library for handling such things. [bcrypt](http://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/) is popular these days. It might have a an exploit, but if it does it'll probably get discovered since there are Trained Cryptoanalysts attacking it every day.

Answer (score 3):

The standard is to *not use the same salt* over and over.  Use, for example, the username as a salt.  Or generate a random salt and add it to the result.

Adding a "secret" doesn't really change anything.  It's just a longer, but still fixed, salt, and you have to distribute it to the servers that check the password, so it really isn't that secret, is it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite common thing in web applications. If hackers get your database, they can search the password as long as they want if they don't know the salt and where it is placed in the string. So a hacker needs *both* the code and the database dump to get the real password.

I can't see any drawback compared to the method without salt, the performance is quite the same while the security obviously increases.

What's more, the salt should be different for every password you encode, you have to choose a salt which is long enough (the longer the better).

For instance, a hacker needs a password table for every salt, which means many calculations. Even if you store the salt in your database, it's a pain for hackers to hack non-standard salts (standard salts can be salts based on the username : *admin*, *root*...)

You can also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes/536756#536756) for more details and explanations.

However, libraries like BCrypt are really nice for cryptography and they are often tested by well-known hackers so I do think you can trust them.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a secret doesn't hurt, and it helps in some scenarios. So I recommend using one, as a defense-in-depth measure.
But in the main scenario password hashing is intended for, it doesn't help: Your server gets compromized, and the attacker learns the secret.

To defend against password guessing attacks, you should use a deliberately slow hash function, namely one of scrypt, bcrypt and PBKDF2.

Your code has two important weaknesses:

1. You're not using a salt. A salt should be different for each user. Standard practice is a random number of 64 or more bits.
2. Single iteration hmac is fast, so use one of the slow schemes I mentioned.

Comment: Doesn't the HMAC key function pretty much the same as a salt in this context?

Comment: @cha0site He's using a constant. A salt should be different for each user.

Comment: He also had a constant password, I assumed that was an example =)

Comment: @cha0site perhaps. But I've seen far too many people using constant salts/IVs to be sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the *best practices*, you might want to read the [OWASP's Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). You'll probably want read [their other cheat sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets) too.