# Linq to sql query for Password field case sensitive

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i write query for Case sensitive in Linq to sql.

Present my query is:

```
   var userResults = from u in Adm.Registrations   
                     where u.UserName == userName && u.Password ==  passWord 
                     select u;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Grab the password hash, wait what? You have plain text passwords?

Comment: Note that changing the collation of your database will determine whether your queries are case insensitive or case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

NEVER, EVER store passwords in plain text in a database or anywhere else.  NEVER.  This is bad.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

> My point here is not to drag the good names of the developers at
>   Reddit through the mud. We're all guilty. I'm sure every developer
>   reading this has stored passwords as plain text at some point in their
>   career. I know I have. Forget the blame. The important thing is to
>   teach our peers that storing plaintext passwords in the database is
>   strictly forbidden-- that there's a better way, starting with basic
>   hashes.

Use these references to help you in determining the best course of action.  There are multiple ways to skin this cat.  I realize that changing the way you store passwords is not a direct answer to your original question, and will involve more work on your part, but it will prevent more headaches down the line.

This is a very thorough guide to solving your plain text issue:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14537/The-Art-Science-of-Storing-Passwords

These links are also illuminating:
[Salting Your Password: Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674904/salting-your-password-best-practices)

[Non-random salt for password hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes/536756#536756)

I hope this is more helpful that just the initial admonition.

Comment: Right now this is not really an answer. You can easily turn it into one by mentioning e.g. how a hash would make things case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't configured your database to perform case-sensitive comparison you will need to perform the comparison in memory, after getting the results from database.

```
var users = Adm.Registrations
               .Where(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == password)
               .ToList() // this will load data into memory
               // Now perform a case-sensitive query on the in-memory data
               .Where(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == password);
```

Another option would be to change the collation of your database to perform case-sensitive search but be carefull as this may cause getting fewer results than expected in other queries or stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var userResults = from u in Adm.Registrations 
                      where u.UserName .Equals(userName,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && u.Password.Equals(passWord,InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                      select u;
```