# Should I use codeigniter's encryption key for hashing passwords?

Tags: php, codeigniter, password-encryption

I've seen in some cases developers that use the encryption key, from the config.php, to hash passwords and store them in database. I was wondering is it better to do it this way, or better by creating a random salt (for example in a function) each time?

Well I guess in the first case you don't have to store (and) the salt in the database, but is it secure enough and what if there's a match with passwords?

Comment: take a look at [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes/536756#536756) to another question why you should use randomly generated salts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use salts to prevent an attacker's brute force attack to amortize across a whole database of hashed passwords. With a unique salt per password, even identical passwords will hash to different hashes, hence forcing an attacker to brute force every single password individually. By using a static salt, which is actually called a *pepper* to distinguish it from a real salt, identical passwords hash to the same hash, hence allowing an attacker to brute force a large set of password hashes much faster (you wouldn't believe how many people use "monkey" as their password).

Therefore:

- unique *salt* per password is a must
- optional *pepper* per password is a slightly added bonus, but only useful if you can keep the pepper *secret* from an attacker

Answer (score 0):

It is true that randomly generated salts produce a greater amount of security, **but** it is also true that anyone who gets access to a list of your password hashes in order to crack them probably has access to your database, in which case they have access to your salts.

Comment: What if i use 2 salts then?? one stored in my database and the second one the encryption_key

Comment: Salts are not meant to be secret in any way!

Comment: @deceze - Of course they are, an unknown salt makes bruteforce decryption against a hash impractical. A known salt just makes it more time consuming.

Comment: Keeping *unique salts per password* secret is impractical. Your application needs the salt, and since the salt needs to be stored with each password individually, if an attacker has access to one he likely also has access to the other. Using *one static secret pepper* is *worse* security than using individual unique "public" salts! Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190.

Comment: *Time consuming* is exactly what you're going for here. If you use *one static secret*, it only needs to be broken once. Using individual unique salts, each hash has to be broken individually. If each hash takes long enough to break individually (because you're using a time consuming hash like bcrypt or scrypt), breaking an entire database of hashes becomes entirely infeasible.

Comment: I tend to use both a static and random secret, but that's just my security paranoia. I'd definitely rather require a database and frontend breakin to essentially dump my users' data than just a database breakin.

Comment: I agree with deceze, a salt is no more secret than the hash itself, and should just be kept with the hash. Thats exactly how it is done with bcrypt.

Answer (score -3):

instead of using anything huge thing for hashing passwords, do use MD5 with salting and everythi

Comment: MD5 is proven to be crackable

Comment: MD5 is not even a option for hashing passwords in modern applications security

Comment: MD5 is not recommended for use in password hashing. The only legitimate use for MD5 these days is for checksumming.